# How to compile and install custom mainline kernel

Tags: kernel, 15.10

I'm running Ubuntu 15.10 on a new laptop but in order to get proper full support for this hardware I apparently need the 4.4 kernel + a custom patch. See [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=204355) if you're interested in the details.

I know about the mainline kernel PPAs but my understanding is that they don't come with source. If this is the case, This would seem to eliminate the possibility of using a mainline kernel PPA because I can't patch it. So I've been trying to check out the git source and build it but can't find up to date, relevant instructions.

Can somebody help with instructions for building a 4.4 kernel on 15.10?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Get and compile the mainline kernel, git method:

see also: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/KernelTeam/GitKernelBuild
I do things a little different (what else is new?).

Prerequisites (Must):

Step 1 is to `apt-get update` and `apt-get dist-upgrade` (i.e. make sure everything is up to date)
Step 2

```
sudo apt-get install fakeroot build-essential crash kexec-tools makedumpfile kernel-wedge
```

Step 3

```
sudo apt-get build-dep linux
```

Step 4

```
sudo apt-get install git-core libncurses5 libncurses5-dev libelf-dev asciidoc binutils-dev
```

Prerequisites as of kernel 4.3:

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

Step 5 - based on not being able to compile on a new 20.04 server installation 2019.12.02

```
sudo apt install flex bison
```

Step 6 - based on not being able to compile kernel 5.13 on a 20.04 server 2021.07.02

```
sudo apt install zstd
```

Prerequisites (Optional):

```
sudo apt-get install git-email git-doc
```

The git part:

```
mkdir temp-k-git
cd temp-k-git
git clone   git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git
cd linux
```

Never do stuff in the default master branch. Always make some work area.

```
git checkout -b k44rc8_stock v4.4-rc8
```

Steal the Ubuntu kernel configuration file (already installed):

```
ls -l /boot
cp /boot/config-4.4.0-040400rc8-generic .config
```

Ubuntu config file has full debugging. Makes an enormous kernel and takes twice as long to compile

```
scripts/config --disable DEBUG_INFO
```

Special note as of Kernel 4.4 and if compiling using Ubuntu 14.04 (I don't know about 15.10), with an older version of the c compiler: It can not compile with CONFIG_CC_STACKPROTECTOR_STRONG.

```
scripts/config --disable CC_STACKPROTECTOR_STRONG
```

If your version doesn't have LZ4 compression (i.e. 16.04) you need also:

```
scripts/config --disable KERNEL_LZ4
scripts/config --enable KERNEL_GZIP
```

Special note as of Kernel 5.12-rc1 one needs to override some newly added certificate stuff.

```
scripts/config --set-str SYSTEM_TRUSTED_KEYS ""
```

or

```
scripts/config --disable SYSTEM_TRUSTED_KEYS
```

Special note as of Kernel 5.14-rc2 one needs to override some more added certificate stuff.

```
scripts/config --disable SYSTEM_REVOCATION_KEYS
```

Compile the kernel:

```
time make -j9 bindeb-pkg       <<< Suggest use number of CPUs + 1. Use less for some responsiveness to be left for other uses
                               <<< I always time the kernel build.
```

or

```
time make -j9 bindeb-pkg LOCALVERSION=-stock    <<< For a localized verion name append
```

or

```
time make -j9 olddefconfig bindeb-pkg LOCALVERSION=-stock   <<< To automatically use defaults for any new config stuff (particuarly useful when bisecting the kernel).
```

When the build has completed, install it:

```
sudo dpkg -i ../linux-headers-4.4.0-rc8-stock_4.4.0-rc8-stock-144_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i ../linux-image-4.4.0-rc8-stock_4.4.0-rc8-stock-144_amd64.deb
```

So, at this point we know the mainline kernel compiles O.K., so move onto the custom kernel. Create a new branch, apply the patches and compile:

```
$ git checkout -b k44rc8_custom v4.4-rc8
Switched to a new branch 'k44rc8_custom'

$ git am plv6_1_3.patch
Applying: cpufreq: intel_pstate: configurable algorithm to get target pstate
$ git am plv6_2_3.patch
Applying: cpufreq: intel_pstate: account for non C0 time
$ git am plv6_3_3.patch
Applying: cpufreq: intel_pstate: Account for IO wait time

$ time make -j9 olddefconfig bindeb-pkg LOCALVERSION=-custom
```

Note that it is on purpose that I do not do a `make clean`, as it is desirable to save a lot of time by doing an incremental build. The first compile took 21 minutes and 26 seconds, but the next custom compile took only 4 minutes and 43 seconds.

Comment: So in this approach I don't apply the Ubuntu kernel patches that create the debian directory right?

Comment: No, it should be exactly as I wrote. Codewise, the mainline ppa should be the same as the kernel.org code. Myself, I have never had much success with debian rules methods.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a quick version how to install on Debian-based distributions:

```sh
# Install dependencies
sudo apt install -y git build-essential kernel-package fakeroot libncurses5-dev libssl-dev ccache

# Clone the kernel
mkdir ~/kernelbuild
cd ~/kernelbuild
git clone --depth=1 -b linux-5.4.y git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git
#                      ^ change kernel branch to the one you're using.
#                        check with `uname -r` and see the available list at www.kernel.org

cd linux-stable

# Build custom kernel
cp /boot/config-`uname -r` .config # copy config from current  kernel
yes '' | make oldconfig
make clean
make -j `getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN` deb-pkg LOCALVERSION=-custom

# Install new kernel
sudo dpkg -i ~/kernelbuild/linux-*.deb

# Reboot
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this simple method. Works fine for my first compilation. One little thing was missing : `sudo chmod -R 0755 linux-stable`

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the page http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.4-rc8-wily you will find a README indicating how to obtain the source files for 4.4rc8

[Instructions for build](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel) are a little confusing.  I've seen several recipes for building the kernels, all a little different.  There are several prerequisites:  There may be some others that are required for the 4.4 kernel

```
sudo apt-get build-dep linux-image-$(uname -r)
sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev
```

Then the commands I have issued for a sucsessful build are:

```
chmod a+x debian/scripts/*
chmod a+x debian/scripts/misc/*
nano debian.master/changelog
fakeroot debian/rules clean
fakeroot debian/rules editconfigs
fakeroot debian/rules binary-headers binary-generic skipabis=true
```

Modifying the changelog file to indicate that I am creating my own kernel, by adding something to the end of the first version number that is shown.

Comment: Thanks. But I had two issues with this: 1) debian/rules didn't have the execute flag, no big deal to add but just a minor variation and 2) The build errored out with `debian/rules.d/2-binary-arch.mk:50: recipe for target '/home/ryan/dev/mainline/debian/stamps/stamp-build-generic' failed` Any ideas?

Comment: @Marplesoft My checkout had the correct flags but my `fakeroot debian/rules clean` has errors when running `debian.master/reconstruct` due to the missing `ubuntu/` directory. I was able to work around this but don't understand why. See my question at http://askubuntu.com/questions/729469/build-ubuntu-kernel-test-mainline-crack-v4-4-kernel-fails-to-clean .