# Install docker on Ubuntu 16.04 - problem with linux-image-extra

Tags: 16.04, docker

I would like to install docker on ubuntu 16.04 (on a virtual server from hosteurope).

The install instructions say I have to install linux-image-*

So I did:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-extra-$(uname -r) linux-image-extra-virtual
```

But the package is not found:

```
Unable to locate package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-042stab120.11
```

Does anybody of you know how to solve this problem?

TIA

Output of apt-cache search linux-image:

```
alsa-base - ALSA driver configuration files
linux-image-4.4.0-21-generic - Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-image-4.4.0-21-lowlatency - Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-21-generic - Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-image-extra-virtual - Transitional package.
linux-image-extra-virtual-lts-utopic - Transitional package. (dummy transitional package)
linux-image-extra-virtual-lts-vivid - Transitional package. (dummy transitional package)
linux-image-extra-virtual-lts-wily - Transitional package. (dummy transitional package)
linux-image-extra-virtual-lts-xenial - Transitional package. (dummy transitional package)
linux-image-generic - Generic Linux kernel image
linux-image-generic-lts-utopic - Generic Linux kernel image (dummy transitional package)
linux-image-generic-lts-vivid - Generic Linux kernel image (dummy transitional package)
linux-image-generic-lts-wily - Generic Linux kernel image (dummy transitional package)
linux-image-generic-lts-xenial - Generic Linux kernel image (dummy transitional package)
linux-image-hwe-generic-trusty - Depends on the generic hardware enablement kernel image (dummy transitional package)
linux-image-hwe-virtual-trusty - Depends on the virtual hardware enablement kernel image (dummy transitional package)
linux-image-lowlatency - lowlatency Linux kernel image
linux-image-lowlatency-lts-utopic - lowlatency Linux kernel image (dummy transitional package)
linux-image-lowlatency-lts-vivid - lowlatency Linux kernel image (dummy transitional package)
linux-image-lowlatency-lts-wily - lowlatency Linux kernel image (dummy transitional package)
linux-image-lowlatency-lts-xenial - lowlatency Linux kernel image (dummy transitional package)
linux-image-virtual - This package will always depend on the latest minimal generic kernel image.
linux-image-virtual-lts-utopic - This package will always depend on the latest minimal generic kernel image. (dummy transitional package)
linux-image-virtual-lts-vivid - This package will always depend on the latest minimal generic kernel image. (dummy transitional package)
linux-image-virtual-lts-wily - This package will always depend on the latest minimal generic kernel image. (dummy transitional package)
linux-image-virtual-lts-xenial - This package will always depend on the latest minimal generic kernel image. (dummy transitional package)
linux-virtual - Minimal Generic Linux kernel and headers
linux-image-4.4.0-22-generic - Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-image-4.4.0-22-lowlatency - Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-image-4.4.0-24-generic - Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-image-4.4.0-24-lowlatency - Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-image-4.4.0-28-generic - Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-image-4.4.0-28-lowlatency - Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-image-4.4.0-31-generic - Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-image-4.4.0-31-lowlatency - Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-image-4.4.0-34-generic - Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-image-4.4.0-34-lowlatency - Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-image-4.4.0-36-generic - Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-image-4.4.0-36-lowlatency - Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-image-4.4.0-38-generic - Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-image-4.4.0-38-lowlatency - Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-image-4.4.0-42-generic - Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-image-4.4.0-42-lowlatency - Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-image-4.4.0-43-generic - Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-image-4.4.0-43-lowlatency - Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-image-4.4.0-45-generic - Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-image-4.4.0-45-lowlatency - Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-image-4.4.0-47-generic - Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-image-4.4.0-47-lowlatency - Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-image-4.4.0-51-generic - Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-image-4.4.0-51-lowlatency - Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-image-4.8.0-28-generic - Linux kernel image for version 4.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-image-4.8.0-28-lowlatency - Linux kernel image for version 4.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-22-generic - Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-24-generic - Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-28-generic - Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-31-generic - Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-34-generic - Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-36-generic - Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-38-generic - Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-42-generic - Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-43-generic - Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-45-generic - Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-47-generic - Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-51-generic - Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-image-extra-4.8.0-28-generic - Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-image-extra-virtual-hwe-16.04-edge - Extra drivers for Virtual Linux kernel image
linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04-edge - Generic Linux kernel image
linux-image-lowlatency-hwe-16.04-edge - lowlatency Linux kernel image
linux-image-virtual-hwe-16.04-edge - Virtual Linux kernel image
linux-virtual-hwe-16.04-edge - Minimal Generic Linux kernel and headers
```

Comment: What is the output of `uname -a`

Comment: uname -a is : Linux lvps46-163-117-78.dedicated.hosteurope.de 4.4.0-042stab120.11 #1 SMP Wed Nov 16 12:05:45 MSK 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/856493/edit) by adding the output of `apt-cache search linux-image`

Comment: run `sudo apt-get install linux-image-4.4.0-42-generic`

Comment: The package is available on `xenial-security main` repo , it should be enabled on your `sources.list`

Comment: get still an error:
...
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-42-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.4.0-42-generic.postinst line 1052.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.4.0-42-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-4.4.0-42-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Answer (score 3):

To install `linux-image-extra` run the following commands :

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install linux-image-4.4.0-51-generic
sudo apt-get install linux-image-extra-4.4.0-51-generic
sudo apt-get install linux-image-extra-virtual
```

Comment: Thank you for the hint. But when I execute `sudo apt-get install linux-image-4.4.0-51-generic` I get errors: 

`
...
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.4.0-51-generic.postinst line 1052.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.4.0-51-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-4.4.0-51-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
`

Answer (score 2):

Here is my approach to *install docker-engine*, see if it helps

I followed the instructions from [docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntulinux/#/install-the-latest-version) official page to install the docker-engine, but i faced the same issue as you did

So, ignored to install the linux-image-extra-* packages`
and went ahead to install docker-engine

```
$apt-get install docker-engine

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 docker-engine : Depends: init-system-helpers (>= 1.18~) but 1.14 is to be installed
                 Depends: lsb-base (>= 4.1+Debian11ubuntu7) but 4.1+Debian11ubuntu6 is to be installed
                 Depends: libdevmapper1.02.1 (>= 2:1.02.97) but 2:1.02.77-6ubuntu2 is to be installed
                 Depends: libltdl7 (>= 2.4.6) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libsystemd0 but it is not installable
                 Recommends: aufs-tools but it is not going to be installed
                 Recommends: cgroupfs-mount but it is not installable or
                             cgroup-lite but it is not going to be installed
```

Ran the following command to see the entry is returned for each version of Docker that is available to install.

```
~# apt-cache policy docker-engine
docker-engine:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.12.5-0~ubuntu-xenial
  Version table:
     1.12.5-0~ubuntu-xenial 0
        500 https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo/ ubuntu-xenial/main amd64 Packages
     1.12.5-0~ubuntu-trusty 0
        500 https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo/ ubuntu-trusty/main amd64 Packages
     1.12.4-0~ubuntu-xenial 0
        500 https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo/ ubuntu-xenial/main amd64 Packages
```

Ran following command to install specific version of docker-engine (From above: Candidate: 1.12.5-0~ubuntu-xenial)

```
apt-get install docker-engine=1.12.5-0~ubuntu-xenial
```

docker installed successfully!

Comment: Apparently the goto unity file system for `Xenial` (4.4 kernel) is [`overlay2`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OverlayFS) --  [Select a storage driver](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/selectadriver/), Docker.com.  _BUT_ a new install last weekend was _expecting_ `aufs` ... Within extras.  _Hmmm_ ... Tonight I'm back working over: [Get Docker CE for Ubuntu](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/).

Answer (score 2):

You may need to install some Linux image extras. Run the below command, and then try again:

```
sudo apt install linux-image-extra-virtual
```

Answer (score 0):

> "Unable to locate package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-042stab120.11"

Your system is not running an ubuntu kernel, but a custom one, built locally for that host, probably, and its kernel packages are not available for download from any repository because they were created by the admin and installed with dpkg (see https://askubuntu.com/a/718662/566214 for details on how a custom kernel is built and installed in Ubuntu and Debian).