# Installing Docker on Ubuntu 14.04 - Unable to locate package linux-image-extra-2.6.32-042stab120.11

Tags: 14.04, apt, kernel, docker

I am trying to install docker according to the [instructions](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntu/).

However, the very first command fails on my system:

```
root@fracz:~# apt-get install curl linux-image-extra-$(uname -r) linux-image-extra-virtual
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-image-extra-2.6.32-042stab120.11
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-image-extra-2.6.32-042stab120.11'
```

I suppose that `uname -r` should return something newer, but I have no idea how to update it. I have seen [similar problem for 16.04 version](https://askubuntu.com/questions/856493/install-docker-on-ubuntu-16-04-problem-with-linux-image-extra) and I'm afraid the answer there may not be valid for 14.04.

Comment: Is it a VPS system?

Comment: Yes, it is VPS.

Comment: That is why you have this old kernel.  And there is no `linux-image-extra-virtual` on Ubuntu.

Comment: So there is no option to update it?

Comment: Just skip it. I do not see a reason to install these packages at all. There may be other problems with that kernel though.

Comment: I have tried that, but then after installation the `service docker status` tells me that the docker is running but the `docker run hello-world` tell me that it *Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?.*.

Comment: A bit late but you need to run it with `sudo`