# do I need to compile whole kernel every time I modify the kernel?

Tags: kernel, compiling

For example, make the whole kernel will take around 1-2 hours. If I only add an entry in system call table, and add a new system call. Do I need to compile the whole system? Is there any short way to do this?

Comment: take a look at [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/125790/do-i-have-to-compile-the-kernel-every-time-even-for-a-small-change)

Comment: Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23279178/how-to-speed-up-linux-kernel-compilation) should be helpful

Comment: If you are using the mainline kernel via git, see [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/718381/how-to-compile-and-install-custom-mainline-kernel/718662#718662). If you are using Ubuntu methods, see [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/865568/re-run-the-kernel-build), and I have asked the poster to answer here.