# Booting got stuck after recompile kernel

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, kernel, compiling

I'm using DigitalOcean's Droplet, which has a 20GB SSD hard disk.
I followed the instruction on [this website](https://medium.freecodecamp.com/building-and-installing-the-latest-linux-kernel-from-source-6d8df5345980#.jfdstzh4s) to recompile the kernel on the Droplet. My system was Ubuntu 16.04 with kernel 4.4.0-generic, and I recompile the kernel 4.4.44 using the same config file in the current system. The compiling process went well but when I power off the Droplet and reboot, I got stuck at "Loading from hard disk".

[Here is the screenshot of the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2hW7.png)

I've tried different kernel version but all get the same result. Please help.

Comment: I would not do it as per your link. I would do it [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/718381/how-to-compile-and-install-custom-mainline-kernel/718662#718662) way. If you do not want to use git, then just start with your unpacked source at the "Steal the Ubuntu kernel configuration file" step.

Comment: @DougSmythies Thanks for your reply. I'm relatively new to Linux, so I chose the tutorial that seemed most easy for me. I will try the method you recommended, but I'm curious about what could be the cause of the problem. Can you give me some insight into this?

Comment: I'm not really sure, but it might be mixing the Ubuntu (Debian) boot methods with other methods. i.e. since you were doing something outside of the normal package management process and boot process, perhaps the system got confused. My suggestion might turn out to be a waste of time for you, not sure, but that is why I made it a comment and not an answer. All I know for certain is that I have never done it your way, but have done it about 800 times my way.

Comment: @DougSmythies Thank you! Your method works! It really saved my day. And I also found a strange thing. After I tried your method, I was able to boot the kernel which I recompiled before (not the one in your method), which previously made me stuck at "loading from hard disk". I tried your method from the very beginning, including the parts before "Steal the Ubuntu kernel configuration file". What could make this happen?

Comment: I don't know. But glad you got it working.