# Compiling the kernel using debian/rules

Tags: kernel, compiling

I downloaded the kernel from the kernel.ubuntu.com repository and I am playing with it.

The kernel can be compiled using make oldconfig, make all and make modules_install. Then the kernel image can be copied to the /boot folder and the modules to the /lib.

So, why there is an another way to do it using debian/rules?

Doesnt it make it more complicated?

My second question is that I ran make mrproper and the directory debian was automatically deleted. How can I restore the debian directory again because all the rules pertaining to the compilation are stored there.

Comment: You can just copy files and such as you mention. However in doing so you are by-passing package management, `dpkg` at the primitive level, `apt` or `apt-get` at the next level. The suggestion is that this is undesirable. I do not believe that using the debian/rules method is new, but rather just a different method resulting in proper .deb file install-able as packages. While it might be considered more complicated, it is also considered more within the Ubuntu package management environment.

Comment: I do not know the answer to your last question. Why not? Because I have never had much success compiling the kernel that way. I only use this [method](http://askubuntu.com/questions/718381/how-to-compile-and-install-custom-mainline-kernel/718662#718662).

Comment: Sounds good. Then I would stick with the packet management instead of copying manually.