# how to compile mainline kernel (from kernel-ppa) with custom version string?

Tags: kernel, compiling

I was able to apply the .patch files and compile the mainline kernel v4.10.10 available at http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.10.10/ following the instructions available on the [wiki](https://Wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel)  and got as a result the desired .deb files, however I have not understood for sure how I can change the version string to a custom one, so that the packages and the kernel string in grub do not conflict With the same generic version already installed.

How can I make this change?

Where can I get more information about more options for this line below used to compile the kernel?

```
fakeroot debian/rules binary-headers binary-generic binary-perarch
```

Thank you for your attention, and sorry for any errors in my English.

Comment: I prefer to use the code directly from [kernel.org](https://www.kernel.org/) and [the git method](https://askubuntu.com/questions/718381/how-to-compile-and-install-custom-mainline-kernel/718662#718662). But it isn't much different to do similar from the tar.xz source file (which I see is now at 4.10.11) if you don't want to get into git.

Comment: @DougSmythies, I agree that getting the source directly from kernel.org is also very cool, but for the sake of learning I'm really keen to be able to modify a Kernel Mainline provided by Ubuntu, that by the way, I used Git to get the source from the Kernel.ubuntu.com.

Anyway thanks for mentioning this other question at ask.ubuntu, I had seen it a few days ago and it helped me to understand some things.