# booting kernel image compiled and built from source (unable to install new image / modify grub bootloader)

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel

I have built kernel from source (3.16 version kernel source taken from kernel.org).

I did all steps of kernel compilation including

```
sudo make module_install
```

Then I copied the bzImage formed with the downloaded source to `/boot` folder. ( I have multiple ubuntu versions installed on multiple partitions, and boot is not a separate partition but as a directory in every root file-system ).

I am now unable to get the new kernel image option in grub boot loader. I have executed  also below command, but could see no modification in `/boot/grub.grub.cfg`

```
sudo grub-mkconfig
```

Comment: Try [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/718381/how-to-compile-and-install-custom-mainline-kernel/718662#718662) method.

Comment: @Doug Smythies , Thank you for the answer and time. I got the answer, I have missed one step - "make install" which did update boot directory with updated kernel image and initram.   The page you had mentioned seemed some different approach, haven't tried that as of now...