# looking for alternative for latest mainline stable kernel deb files to replace defunct kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/

Tags: upgrade, kernel

Am trying to upgrade to 4.11 kernel, and would like to be able tp upgrade to every mainline stable kernel as I have before on the kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/ site. There are no clear guides on how to do this, every guide points to kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/ which is abandoned. All the guides to compiling custom kernels are out of date . So Where is a working alternative to kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/ ?

Comment: I use [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/718381/how-to-compile-and-install-custom-mainline-kernel/718662#718662) method. I used the Ubuntu kernel 4.11-rc8 kernel configuration file.

Comment: I cant get 4.11rc8  to work. its on  kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/ however I  tried the method you linked to twice and it didnt work with 4.11 . I cant tell if it was because of 4.11 or if I had an error in configuring it, or if it is too out of date. Additionally the patches in the end, are they required?

Comment: I do not apply any patches to the mainline kernel. The procedure I use still works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu Mainline Kernel Installer is your answer!

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cappelikan/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mainline
```

Then after installing you can either use the GUI or the command-line if you're scripting automation.

Details and documentation here... https://github.com/bkw777/mainline