# Apply menuconfig changes on current kernel

Tags: kernel, compiling, configuration, make

I am a newbie and I want to change a small option in the networking option (enable DCCP's CCID3).
I used:

> make menuconfig

and saved the changes to .config 
I have looked through tens and tens of tutorials and questions but none answer my question. I just want to apply this  small change to my current kernel. That's it. However, all of the tutorials tell you to build a new kernel (which I do not want to do) and when I attempted to do that by typing

> make

in /usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-72, I got the following errors:

> arch/x86/Makefile:148: CONFIG_X86_X32 enabled but no binutils support
>   Makefile:693: Cannot use CONFIG_CC_STACKPROTECTOR_STRONG: -fstack-protector-strong not supported by compiler
>   scripts/kconfig/conf  --silentoldconfig Kconfig
>   *** Error during update of the configuration.
>   scripts/kconfig/Makefile:37: recipe for target 'silentoldconfig' failed
>   make[2]:**  [silentoldconfig] Error 1
>   Makefile:552: recipe for target 'silentoldconfig' failed
>   make[1]:  **[silentoldconfig] Error 2
>   make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_32.tbl', needed by 'arch/x86/entry/syscalls/../../include/generated/asm/syscalls_32.h'.  Stop.
>   arch/x86/Makefile:199: recipe for target 'archheaders' failed
>   make: *** [archheaders] Error 2

I am really stuck. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: It seems you might be compiling with an older version of the compiler, in which case you need to disable stuff that needs `STACKPROTECTOR_STRONG`. I would just do this: `scripts/config --disable CC_STACKPROTECTOR_STRONG`.

Comment: This is not a Debian way to build a kernel.

Answer (score 1):

You do need to compile the kernel after changing the config.  The config in question is the configuration used to compile the kernel.  Its not configuration for the running kernel.  Config for a running kernel typically done via the /proc filesystem.

Comment: Correct except for the `/proc` part - nowadays it's normally `/sys`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you just found tutorials on how to compile a new kernel is that it is not possible to just change a little part. You will have to build an entire new kernel.

The way to go is probably to copy over your current kernels configuration (should be located in */boot* , e.g. /boot/config-4.4.0-112-generic) to your kernel source tree

```
cp /boot/config-4.4.0-112-generic /where/your/sources/are/.config
```

go to your kernel sources and execute

```
make menuconfig
```

From there on you will be able to follow any tutorial I guess. There is however quite some work ahead of you (e.g. building the initial ramdisk)

This is the bare metal way to go and build a kernel. Good for educational purposes but not convenient in the long run. There is plenty of information on the web how to do this better (e.g [How to compile and install custom mainline kernel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/718381/how-to-compile-and-install-custom-mainline-kernel))