# How to disable make clean after trying to make kernel again?

Tags: kernel, compiling

I waited a long time for my kernel to compile, but in the end it said I should run with fakeroot to create the debian packages. I installed fakeroot and run again, but instead of using the already built object files, it started compiling everything again.

How to stop make from cleaning in the second time I compile?

Comment: What command(s) did you run exactly ?

Comment: I never did figure out how to do incremental kernel compiles using Ubuntu methods. And yes, it is annoying. I only use [this method](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1007406/how-to-disable-make-clean-after-trying-to-make-kernel-again) now. On my system a clean compile takes about 28 minutes, but an incremental compile can be as short as 5 minutes, depending on how many changes.

Comment: @Panther : Dough!!! I meant [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/718381/how-to-compile-and-install-custom-mainline-kernel/718662#718662)