# Can't see compiled kernel in grub list

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel, compiling

I have just compiled my kernel for the first time, at the end everything went well and I got no erros, but i still can't see it at the list of Available kernels in the grub. I use ubuntu 18.04, does anyone know what happened?
I have followed these steps:

1. extracted the kernel into the folder `/usr/src`
2. `make menuconfig`. Got no error
3. `make bzImage`. No error
4. `make modules`. No error
5. `make modules_install`. No error
6. `make install`. No error
7. in the folder /boot i did `mkinitramfs -o initrd.img-4.17.2 4.17.2`
8. last but not leat i updated the grup. `update-grub`

After last step i saw that the new compiled kernel was listed in the terminal's output but after i rebooted the system the new kernel wasn't there. What can i do to have it there?

A secondary question. Is that safe to remove files and folders created during the process inside `/usr/src` directory?

Comment: I think, but am not sure, you need to compile your kernel such that debian packages are made, then install them using `dpkg -i`. Then they will appear in the grub kernel list during boot. Subsequently, you can purge the kernel using dpkg also.

Comment: So, after all that proccess i have to take the resulting files in the new folder i created in /boot, turn it into a .deb package and them install it?

Comment: Yes. There should be a make command parameter such that you end up with .deb files. I don't compile your way, I do it [this way](https://askubuntu.com/questions/718381/how-to-compile-and-install-custom-mainline-kernel/718662#718662).

Comment: Ill take a look at it right now, will post here soon

Comment: so, that way is a bit more complicated than the way i did my compilation, but thanks for the link and i'll take a carefull loot at it later (more information for me :D)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I tried "update-grub" again and id didn't work, but I tried to do the same in my manjaro instalation and it now works well, seems like every grub-change must be donne in Manjaro I dont know why.