# There is no new builds from Ubuntu Mainline from 01.19

Tags: kernel, ppa

Yesterday I noticed on kernel PPA mainline that the last build is on 19th of January 2019, which is 5 days back. I was hoping to try the new 5.0 rc3. Daily build are also from 19th. After some digging around I found:

```
/home/kernel-ppa/kteam-tools/mainline-build/mainline-work-kmsgq cod-changeset-build 'disco' 'linux' 'crack' 'cod/changeset/disco/hash--0ee7e06f2fa5b1d3b3defabddc4fcab28fa2e1d2' 'LP#1809046'  # Out of disk space
```

There is problem, or they are doing some maintenance?

Edit: I think that after system update, there is problem with git-build-recipe.

```
RUN ['git-build-recipe', '--safe', '--no-build', '--manifest', '/home/buildd/build-RECIPEBRANCHBUILD-2025873/chroot-autobuild/home/buildd/work/tree/manifest', '--distribution', 'cosmic', '--allow-fallback-to-native', '--append-version', '~ubuntu18.10.1', '/home/buildd/build-RECIPEBRANCHBUILD-2025873/chroot-autobuild/home/buildd/work/recipe', '/home/buildd/build-RECIPEBRANCHBUILD-2025873/chroot-autobuild/home/buildd/work/tree']
usage: git-build-recipe [-h] [--manifest PATH] [--if-changed-from PATH]
                        [--package PACKAGE] [--distribution DISTRIBUTION]
                        [--no-build] [--append-version APPEND_VERSION]
                        [--safe] [--allow-fallback-to-native]
                        LOCATION [WORKING-BASEDIR]
git-build-recipe: error: No control file to take the package name from, and --package not specified.
```

Comment: The mainline PPA breaks about 2 or 3 times per year. Sometimes the kernel team doesn't seem to notice until someone tells them, which I have often done via IRC. I am not familiar with `git-build-recipe`, but did not have an issue compiling kernel 5.0-rc3 myself, using the method detailed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/718381/how-to-compile-and-install-custom-mainline-kernel/718662#718662).

Comment: Can you notice them please, because I don't use IRC at all.

Comment: It 's [there](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.0-rc3/) now.

Comment: All is working now.