# Continue custom kernel creation and not start over again from square one

Tags: kernel, scripts, compiling, makefile

**Task:**
Create a custom Ubuntu kernel from git sources (in my case hwe-branch).

**Short summary:**

I want to fix a error reported by the build scripts and then repeat only the last compilation/packaging step that failed when compiling a custom kernel.

**Longer problem description:**

I want to know if it is possible to continue with custom kernel creation without having to build/compile everything from scratch over and over again. I understand so far, that (at least for Xenial 16.04) there are some makefiles in `./debian/rules.de` which do all the kernel compilation work.

However, after finding out why a certain compilation/packaging step failed and then correcting the issue (e.g. wrong proxy configuration and therefore installing of spl-dkms from an online repo failed) I want to continue after the last successful step.

I tried to identify the responsible parts in the makefile (in most cases it was `./xenial/debian/rules.d/2-binary-arch.mk`) and tried to comment out the actual compilation which takes the most time (the part beginning with `# Do the actual build, including image and modules)`.

Unfortunately, this strategy doesn't seem to work. Building the kernel always fails later on for reasons that are beyond my Linux kernel creation skills, often requesting a run of `make mrproper` which also erases the `./debian` subdir containing the build scripts and thus making the entire build environment dysfunctional.

Is it possible to avoid repeating the compilation of the whole kernel because of minor issues that are easy to fix?

Comment: It is possible to do an incremental compile, but I have never figured out how for the Ubuntu method. For the [mainline kernel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/718381/how-to-compile-and-install-custom-mainline-kernel/718662#718662), I do incremental compiles all the time.

Comment: Thank you. But using the Ubuntu config files on the mainline kernel does not give me the Ubuntu kernel, correct? My understanding was that there are Debian/Ubuntu patches applied to mainline kernel before compiling.

Comment: Yes, correct, you do not get the Ubuntu kernel. My point was that incremental compiles are possible. By the way, I use mainline kernels on my 16.04 server all the time.