# How can I build the kernel without compiling everything if I did that previously?

Tags: kernel, compiling

I rebuild the kernel based on the git sources. These are the steps that I take:

1. git clone git://kernel.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-focal.git
2. cd  ubuntu-focal
3. vi debian.master/changelog
4. apply patches
5. fakeroot debian/rules clean binary-headers binary-generic

If I then apply another patch and want to compile the same version again, I get an error because certain folders are not empty. I can issue 'fakeroot debian/rules clean' to solve that, but then I need to compile the whole kernel.

Is there a way to recompiling only the changed files and build the debs based on that? It seems a trivial thing I just haven't figured out yet.

Comment: Kernel subsystems and modules are compiled separately before being merged into the kernel. I just want to avoid recompiling the exact same source code for the source files that haven't changed.

Comment: I never did figure out how to do an incremental kernel compile the Ubuntu way. I do it almost always with the upstream git source. Method described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/718381/how-to-compile-and-install-custom-mainline-kernel/718662#718662).

Comment: Do `dch -i` and compile. There should be no problems. I always do it this way.

Comment: That would not work. Redid the test:  
mv: cannot move '/git/linux-stable-5.5/debian/linux-modules-5.5.3-050503-generic/lib/modules/5.5.3-050503-generic/kernel' to '/git/linux-stable-5.5/debian/linux-modules-extra-5.5.3-050503-generic/lib/modules/5.5.3-050503-generic/kernel/kernel': Directory not empty
debian/rules.d/2-binary-arch.mk:113: recipe for target 'install-generic' failed
make: *** [install-generic] Error 1

Answer (score 1):

So it is not exactly what I was looking for, but as I am mainly looking to save some time and can spare the diskspace I adopted ccache based on [this](http://linuxdeveloper.blogspot.com/2012/05/using-ccache-to-speed-up-kernel.html) guide.

I use the method described [here](https://ahelpme.com/linux/ubuntu/build-your-own-kernel-under-ubuntu-using-mainline-latest-kernel) to compile the kernel, with the exception that I pull in the sources from GregKH's stable tree.

I added this to .bashrc:

```
export CCACHE_DIR="/scrap/ccache"
export CC="ccache gcc"
export CXX="ccache g++"
export PATH="/usr/lib/ccache:$PATH"
```

But it seems I have to add the parameter when invoking the build:

```
CC="ccache gcc" fakeroot debian/rules binary-headers binary-generic
```

Results after 2 identical builds look good (starting with empty cache then doing a build with everything in cache equals 50% hit rate in total):

> cache hit (direct)                 20354
>   cache hit (preprocessed)              81
>   cache miss                         20411
>   cache hit rate                     50.03 %
>   called for link                       94
>   called for preprocessing             148
>   unsupported code directive            12
>   no input file                       1329
>   cleanups performed                     0
>   files in cache                     61169
>   cache size                           7.3 GB
>   max cache size                      16.0 GB

Regular Kernel builds took slightly over an hour. The first ccache run (filling the cache) took 95 minutes. The second build 30 minutes. I'm keeping it like this for now.