# Newly compiled kernel hangs at boot with no output

Tags: boot, kernel, compiling, logging

I need to develop some stuff in the kernel for my honours project but im stuck at simply getting a stock kernel to compile and boot.

I've followed a few recipes but all of them just result in the following messages with NO other output or errors:

```
Loading Linux 5.7.11 ...
Loading initial ramdisk ...
```

After that it just stops. I've left it for hours with no change.

I've tried removing as many variables as possible and am mainly following this tutorial: https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/compiling-linux-kernel-26.html.

I've also done the exact same tutorial on VirtualBox and it works fine, so I'm thinking it's something specific to my Lenovo Ideapad S145. But I just don't know where to start debugging as there is just no output or error messages at all.

I should also add that I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:
The exact process I use for comipling and installing is:

Download the latest stable from https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v5.x/linux-5.7.11.tar.xz

```
unxz -v linux-5.7.11.tar.xz
tar -xvf linux-5.7.11.tar.xz
cd linux-5.7.11
cp /boot/config-5.4.0-42-generic .config
make menuconfig
```

Then I dont change anything and just save straight away

```
make -j 4
sudo make modules_install
sudo make install
```

The "make install" part does all the grub setup for me, then I just reboot and it gets stuck.
These exact steps work on virtualbox but dont on my real Lenovo laptop.

Comment: You need to see the boot messages. Either boot the broken kernel, reboot and run `journalctl -e -b 1` to see the log output of the last boot, or else edit `/etc/default/grub` in a working kernel, find the line that starts GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT and you'll probably see `quiet splash`, alter that to `debug` and save, then run `sudo update-grub` and reboot to the broken kernel; you'll then see the output of the boot log as you boot. Hopefully, this will give some indication of the problem.

Comment: try [this method](https://askubuntu.com/questions/718381/how-to-compile-and-install-custom-mainline-kernel/718662#718662).

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys. @Do
I did some tests and ive put "loglevel=7 debug" into the grub config, and when i boot my working kernel there is a butt ton of messages, but still none from my compiled kernel.
I also did a test where I first booted the broken kernel and noted the time, then 10minutes latter I booted the working kernel, so that i could differentiate them in journalctl. Unfortunatly it looks like the broken kernel isnt even getting to the stage of logging anything in journal control :-/ .

Comment: @DougSmythies Im about to commute home for the day, but once im there, ill try your method.

Comment: It is unclear how you build kernels and how you install them. For me it works.

Comment: @Pilot6 ah sorry, ive just added an edit to show the exact steps that Ive been doing.

Comment: This is a wrong way to compile kernels for Ubuntu. Also maybe Secure Boot is enabled.

Comment: @Pilot6 ah okay I see, though im still a little confused as it worked fine with the same version of Ubuntu on VirtualBox.
How would you recommend I compile for Ubuntu 20?

Comment: VirtualBox doesn't have Secure Boot. You can get the latest mainline kernels already compiled for Ubuntu [here](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/). You can also get debianized sources from git and build them using `debian/rules`. Using `make install` is completely wrong.

Comment: ah sorry guys, i should have replied to this earlier.
I got it working by following @DougSmythies method.
I just added the "bindeb-pkg" parameter which builds the .dep packages and installing them worked. So ultimately I think I must have been doing somethings wrong when generating the initram or installing the kernel.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of building the mainline kernel with make and installing it with make install you probably are better to try building a debian packaging from the kernel source and installing the .debs.  That way you can easily remove it too.

```
unxz -v linux-5.7.11.tar.xz
tar -xvf linux-5.7.11.tar.xz
cd linux-5.7.11
cp /boot/config-5.4.0-42-generic .config

make deb-pkg INSTALL_MOD_STRIP=1
cd ..
sudo dpkg -i *deb
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using grub (which it looks like you are) press e on the boot entry to temporerally edit it and remove the line saying `gfxpayload=keep`.

I've had this same issue before and removing that grub option fixed it. To make this permanent edit the `/etc/default/grub` file and look for a line saying `GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep` and delete it.