# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS after building custom kernel boot freezes at "Loading Initial Ramdisk..."

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, kernel, freeze

[image]

I updated my grub in my Ubuntu 20.04 after building my new kernel which is version 5.8.18. After this process, I checked my /boot directory the following were present,

1. **vmlinuz-5.8.18**
2. **initrd.img-5.8.18**
3. **System.map-5.8.18** and
4. **config-5.8.18.**

In **/var/lib/initramfs-tools/ my 5.8.18 file** is present. So I don't know where I am doing wrong.

But once I boot into this kernel. I get **"Loading Initial RamDisk ..."** and my boot freezes. Anybody can help me out please… I have been held up here for more than a week. I tried building around 5 kernels. Every time I build it, boot freezes and the same issue pertains.

Do the linux-headers-version play a vital role in loading the temporary root file system into the initial ramdisk during the boot process. Because my current working kernel which is **"5.4.0-53-generic"** has a **"linux-headers-5.4.0-53-generic directory"** in the `/usr/src` location.

I used the following commands to build my kernel,

1. `mkdir kernel`
2. `cd kernel`
3. `git clone -b linux-5.8.y git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git`
4. `cd linux-stable/`
5. `make mrproper`
6. `cp /boot/config-`uname -r `.config`
7. `yes '' | make oldconfig`
8. `make menuconfig`
9. `make -j 4`
10. `make modules_install`
11. `make install`
12. `cd /boot; mkinitramfs -k 5.8.18 -o initrd.img-5.8.18`
13. `sudo update-grub`

My mail id is sudesh.skofficial@gmail.com Thanks in advance :).

I am using **Mi Notebook 14 from Xaomi which is a Intel Core i5** system.

Comment: Is this a desktop system and *why exactly* are you trying to build a new kernel?

Comment: Hello @KGIII!
          Yeah this is a Desktop system. I am building a new kernel to get the recent stable version and as well reduce its size since it has unnecessary drivers and other stuff. P.S. I am rookie in the Linux Kernel Development, sir. I am just doing this to understand how things work while building a new kernel.

Comment: Alright. I asked because I'd wondered if [this](https://github.com/bkw777/mainline) might suit your needs, but it does not.

Comment: You sent me an e-mail asking me to look at this: I have never been able to compile the Ubuntu versions of the kernel, I only compile and do custom/development stuff on the mainline (upstream) kernel. My method is [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/718381/how-to-compile-and-install-custom-mainline-kernel/718662#718662).

Comment: Thanks a ton for checking my email and helping me out, sir!

Answer (score 1):

Please confirm your initrd.img file size.
The solution is here.

```
$ sudo make modules_install INSTALL_MOD_STRIP=1
```