# Compiling kernel 5.11.11 and later

Tags: kernel, compiling

In Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, I was compiling kernel 5.11.11 after adding a new system call. I also get this with later Ubuntu versions and kernels. During the execution of make command I got this error:

```
make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'debian/canonical-certs.pem', needed by 'certs/x509_certificate_list'.  Stop.
make: *** [Makefile:1809: certs] Error 2
```

If someone can help I would really appreciate it, Thank you.

Comment: Did you modify the value of `CONFIG_SYSTEM_TRUSTED_KEYS` in configuration?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

In your kernel configuration file you will find this line:

```
CONFIG_SYSTEM_TRUSTED_KEYS="debian/canonical-certs.pem"
```

Change it to this:

```
CONFIG_SYSTEM_TRUSTED_KEYS=""
```

Depending on your source structure you might be able to do it via command line. Examples:

```
scripts/config --disable SYSTEM_TRUSTED_KEYS
```

or

```
scripts/config --set-str SYSTEM_TRUSTED_KEYS ""
```

EDIT: Another key has been added to the default Canonical kernel configuration since this answer was posted:

```
CONFIG_SYSTEM_REVOCATION_KEYS="debian/canonical-revoked-certs.pem"
```

So, it also needs to be dealt with for user kernel compiles to complete:

```
scripts/config --disable SYSTEM_REVOCATION_KEYS
```

See also [git based mainline kernel compile notes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/718381/how-to-compile-and-install-custom-mainline-kernel/718662#718662).

Comment: Thankyou so much

Comment: you can edit it through the menuconfig by running "make menuconfig"

Comment: Do you mind explaining a bit why you need to do this, like why do you think the canonical cert was in there to begin with and why it's ok to just remove it?

Comment: @Shanteva : If one does not do it, then the kernel will not compile, as per the question. I assume it was added for [additional kernel security](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.13/security/keys/trusted-encrypted.html). I do not know your requirements, so can not comment if it is ok to remove it for you or if you need to provide some other trusted key. For me, and I assume some others, it is fine to remove it. Note that it has been there for a long time, but Canonical just started using it.

Comment: I mean why as in, .config explicitly says not to edit it, so why is that value set to begin with, and what would be the "proper" way of giving the build system what it wants with that value

Comment: I don't really expect you to answer, but I think this is a pretty obvious question to ask

Comment: @Shanteva : the second and third way of my answer are official ways, as is the the way in the comments using menuconfig. Myself, I rarely use menuconfig.

Comment: @DougSmythies maybe it is worth to add that the same steps are needed for `CONFIG_SYSTEM_REVOCATION_KEYS`. At least while compiling Kernel version 5.13. So `scripts/config --disable CONFIG_SYSTEM_REVOCATION_KEYS`

Comment: @garlix : Agreed. Answer edited.

Comment: @yehudahs Where in the menuconfig is this found?

Comment: @Shanteva Nobody has answered WHY these values are set as they are yet, really.  It's for building the Ubuntu signed kernels.  BIOS boot? Don't need signed kernels.  EFI? Don't need signed kernels.  EFI with secure boot?  The boot loader (grub), kernel, and modules, must be signed.  The Ubuntu kernel source's debian/ directory does include those .pem files.

Answer (score 8):

Well, I just generated a self-signed x509 certificate with a common name as my name, put the key and certificate in the same file and pointed both lines to the file. Compiles perfectly and security should be intact. I assume it's used to sign kernel binary and you can whitelist your certificate in a secure boot to allow your kernel to boot.

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout certs/mycert.pem -out certs/mycert.pem -nodes -days 3650
```

```
CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_KEY="certs/mycert.pem"
CONFIG_SYSTEM_TRUSTED_KEYRING=y
CONFIG_SYSTEM_TRUSTED_KEYS="certs/mycert.pem"
CONFIG_SYSTEM_EXTRA_CERTIFICATE=y
CONFIG_SYSTEM_EXTRA_CERTIFICATE_SIZE=4096
CONFIG_SECONDARY_TRUSTED_KEYRING=y
CONFIG_SYSTEM_BLACKLIST_KEYRING=y
CONFIG_SYSTEM_BLACKLIST_HASH_LIST=""
```

Comment: this is the way to go

Comment: trying this caused problem for me, check this kernel doc for more details https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/admin-guide/module-signing.rst, this post helped me to fix the issue https://github.com/andikleen/simple-pt/issues/8

Answer (score 5):

Just executed following two commands in after running **"make menuconfig"**

```
scripts/config --disable SYSTEM_TRUSTED_KEYS
scripts/config --disable SYSTEM_REVOCATION_KEYS
```

while **"make"** command is running, if any certificate related question arises, then simply hit **Enter**. That's it.

Comment: This is so much more convenient than scrambling around a large file with vim.

Comment: linked problem https://askubuntu.com/questions/1504022/kernel-6-7-5-compile-error-ubuntu-22-04-no-rule-to-make-target-debian-canonical