# I am installing kernel in my ubuntu but getting an error

Tags: kernel

make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'debian/canonical-revoked-certs.pem' , needed by certs/x509_revocation_list'. STOP.
make: ***[Makefile:1851:certs] Error 2

Comment: This question lacks sufficient details and context to understand the problem. It is unlikely to be answered in its current state. Please edit your question and include more details. You should include all steps and commands needed to reproduce your problem as well as the complete error.  You should also tell us the version and flavor of Ubuntu you are using and include a description about what you are trying to do, with examples.  Please [format](https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting) your post appropriately so that we can tell the difference between commands, output, and narrative.

Comment: see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1329538/compiling-the-kernel-5-11-11/1329625#1329625) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/718381/how-to-compile-and-install-custom-mainline-kernel/718662#718662). Do this: `scripts/config --disable SYSTEM_REVOCATION_KEYS`

Comment: What version Ubuntu? What kernel? Where did you get this kernel? When/how do you see this error? Details...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compiling the kernel 5.11.11](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1329538/compiling-the-kernel-5-11-11)

Answer (score 5):

I just copy the answer from @Doug and the problem fixed:
`scripts/config --disable SYSTEM_REVOCATION_KEYS`

Comment: It looks as if you've (accidentally, I presume) created a duplicate account.  Follow the instructions at this link to merge your accounts: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/6319/how-to-request-for-merging-my-2-askubuntu-accounts

Answer (score 0):

The files are contained in the source package of the linux image. You can download it with pull-lp-source, e.g.

```
pull-lp-source linux-riscv kinetic
```

for the Kinetic riscv64 kernel.