# Missing libc6 Dependency for a new Kernel (5.16.2)

Tags: kernel, dependencies

I just manually installed the mainline 5.16.2 kernel. I need it for the new alder lake cpu/igpu support.

The problem is that the headers for this kernel were not installed (and not installable), since a newer version of `libc6` is required, as well as `libssl`.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-headers-5.16.2-051602-generic : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but 2.31-0ubuntu9.2 is installed
                                       Depends: libssl3 (>= 3.0.0~~alpha1) but it is not installable
```

Is there a workaround? If not, I can attempt and compile and configure the kernel from scratch, but all the links and guides I found about that are incredibly old, so I don't trust them.

**EDIT**: I'm on Kubuntu 20.04. I have an Alder Lake CPU, and also a Nvidia A6000 video card. The integrated graphics on Alder Lake has to provide the video output, so that the A6000 is left alone for computation.
That's why I needed the 5.16 kernel.

**EDIT2**: I solved the problem by uplifting my whole distro to 22.04. Hardly the best solution (for obvious reasons).

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? Do you have Nvidia card?

Comment: There is [a bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1926938), and it includes some workarounds. See also [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1329538/compiling-the-kernel-5-11-11/1329625#1329625) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/718381/how-to-compile-and-install-custom-mainline-kernel/718662#718662).

Comment: You've not provided release details; but packages in your message that meet the requirements are available, but not for all releases.  Are you expecting us to guess you're on *focal*?  Why not provide such detail?  5.16 is not a supported kernel for Ubuntu, being only *testing*, but can be installed if you're on the right release.

Comment: Excuse me for not witing a more detailed question. Editing right now.

Comment: To help other users I would recommend to move EDIT2 to the answer section below.

Comment: @N0rbert Why not installing the package manually? My answer explains the reason for the same.

Comment: @N0rbert: because it could break something else and/or cause some dependecy hell. Also, I wouldn't move EDIT2 in the answers, for using an alpha distribution is hardly recommendable for any serious usage scenario. I did it only becuase I couldn't do otherwise.

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 doesn't yet exist; it's currently the *development* release Ubuntu *jammy* and remains that until it reaches RC state which isn't expected until after 14 April 2022, and isn't on-topic here until release on 21 April 2022.  https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/jammy-jellyfish-release-schedule/23906  Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic.  For support issues with Ubuntu *jammy* you'll need to use a #ubuntu-next or #ubuntu+1 site (IRC, UF etc)

Comment: Indeed I did **NOT** request support about 22.04, not I started any discussion about it. I merely stated that I installed it as a temporary solution.
I asked about 20.04, and my question still stands.

Comment: 20.04 is currently transitioning to 20.04.4 if using HWE; the issues you require aren't needed by a *focal* system until it transitions to 20.04.5 which is ~6 months into the future; testing for it hasn't started yet on a *focal* base  (it's not yet *stable* in *jammy* where issues get resolved before it starts getting back-ported to *focal* after *jammy* has reached *stable* and been released).

Comment: @N0rbert I can see that kernel 5.16 is available in the tuxinvader PPA. Which is available for 20.04. What about that? Can **I** post an answer about it?

Comment: @N0rbert https://launchpad.net/~tuxinvader/+archive/ubuntu/lts-mainline

Comment: Of course you can, but Nvidia driver may fail to compile on this kernel because of its version. This moment needs testing on VM first

Comment: @N0rbert Tested on a VM of Ubuntu 20.04 focal.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this can't be answered by anyone. The clear answer is NO, you cannot solve this issue. There's no way to install kernel 5.16 on focal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**: Upgrade your system to 21.10 or wait for 22.04 to be released; Kernel 5.16 is unstable.

There are two problems, `libc6` and `libssl3`.

- **`libc6`**: `libc6` version 2.34 is only available in Ubuntu 21.10. The kernel 5.16 cannot run without this library.
- **`libssl3`**: Ubuntu mainline kernel 5.15.7+ and 5.16 bumps the requirement from `libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.0)` to `libssl3 (>= 3.0.0~~alpha1)`. However, package `libssl3` is **not** [available for Ubuntu 21.10 *impish indri*.](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libssl3&searchon=names&suite=impish&section=all). It's only [available for Ubuntu 22.04 *jammy jellyfish*](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libssl3&searchon=names&suite=jammy&section=all) which is not yet released.

**After reading the above we can conclude that one can  <s>NOT</s>  install kernel 5.16 on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS *focal fossa*.**

Don't want to lose hope? There are a few things to try.

- Most of the drivers from 5.16 are also available in 5.13.9, you can try installing that kernel.
- Upgrade to Ubuntu 21.10
- Upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04
- **There is a PPA for mainline kernels available for LTS.**
  If you'd like to test the PPA then run the following commands:

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tuxinvader/lts-mainline
  sudo apt update
  ```

  Install the kernel:

  ```
  sudo apt update
  sudo apt install linux-5.16.2
  sudo apt -f install
  ```
- You may try installing all the packages manually from deb files but they may fully break, It may convert your system to a toaster! Don't go for that.
- The only thing to try is temporarily adding the Jammy repositories and manually installing the correct version of packages. But Jammy repositories are unstable and they may also convert your system to a toaster!

**N.B**: If you're using NVIDIA graphics cards, your drivers may fail to compile. Kernel 5.16 is mainline and pretty unstable. Make sure to have a backup before doing something that can convert your system into a toaster ;)

<sub>"toaster" means it can make your system unopertable. Just like using Linux on a toaster.</sub>

Comment: Also, I'll wipe my 22.04 installation and try with 21.10 & 5.16, ASAP.