# Kernel 6.7.2 issues

Tags: upgrade, kernel, 22.04, compiling

this is mine first time compile a kernel and I have this error

```
make[3]: *** No hay ninguna regla para construir el objetivo 'debian/canonical-certs.pem', necesario para 'certs/x509_certificate_list'.  Alto.
make[3]: *** Se espera a que terminen otras tareas....
  CC      certs/system_keyring.o
  CC      kernel/sched/core.o
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:480: certs] Error 2
make[2]: *** Se espera a que terminen otras tareas....
```

I wish to know how can I fix this issues and upgrade my kernel to the current kernel please and thanks , and sorry if my English it is a little odd , the English language is not my mother tongue

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compiling the kernel 5.11.11](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1329538/compiling-the-kernel-5-11-11)

Comment: No quiet , I try the command of that forum but it still say the same think

Comment: There are two commands. Just run `scripts/config --disable SYSTEM_TRUSTED_KEYS; scripts/config --disable SYSTEM_REVOCATION_KEYS`. If that doesn't work, manually edit the config file to remove the value from those two keys

Comment: Mainline Kernels are still in development and can be prone to failures.  You are more than welcome to use them, but you should be prepared to report bugs and failures to the canonical developers.  We more than likely will not be able to help you.  Is there a reason why you are trying to install a mainline Kernel?

Comment: Are you looking for the prebuilt mainline kernels? It's slightly better to download the 4 amd64 .deb files from https://kernel.ubuntu.com/mainline/v6.7.2/ and `sudo dpkg -i 1.deb 2.deb 3.deb 4.deb` instead of building.

Comment: To answer the Terrance question , I just want the latest version of Linux , that means the programs and the kernel as well , I understand the risk, but that is part of the fun on Linux by my view of the thinks , and about Daniel , I try to install via that way but the dependings keep me error with another to another , and another guy in other forms say "compile" and I said ok so.. here's we are , try to learn how compile a current kernel to my old laptop pentium :)

Comment: @RicardoAndresRiquelmeRios You have to install download all 4 files and put them all on the same command line. Anyway, you say you "want the latest version of Linux , that means the programs and the kernel", but you are on 22.04. I would avoid messing with the kernel version for now. Just repeat `sudo do-release-upgrade` from 22.04 to 22.10 to 23.04 to 23.10. Then do `do-release-upgrade -d` to 24.04. That way you would have the ***newest Ubuntu*** possible, with newer kernel and apps tested to be working together. Any newer, and you need to find another distro.

Comment: Mm ok ,  with all respect, I think I gonna find another place to find help , thanks for give me some of your time to answer my questions