# mainline kernel now depends on libc6 2.33, non-installable in focal?

Tags: 20.04, kernel, compiling, glibc

I've been happily installing 5.10 mainline kernels (from [https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/)) on my Ubuntu 20.04.

Trying to update to 5.10.33, I discovered an unwelcome dependency on libc >=2.33 (focal is at 2.31) for the `-headers` package (though not the image itself -- but who wants to live without the headers).

AFAIK, libc6 is next to impossible to upgrade. Is this... it? Am I stuck at 5.10.32 unless I give up LTS? Do these folks even have a public-facing site where one can report bugs?

**Update**: This seems to be the main [launchpad bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1926938). A good thing that came out of it: [tuxinvader](https://github.com/TuxInvader) has come up with a [Docker container](https://hub.docker.com/r/tuxinvader/focal-mainline-builder) (source on Github: [focal-mainline-builder](https://github.com/TuxInvader/focal-mainline-builder)) for building kernel mainline images and uploaded 5.10 - 5.12 packages to his PPAs:

- [tuxinvader's lts-mainline-longterm PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Etuxinvader/+archive/ubuntu/lts-mainline-longterm)
- [tuxinvader's lts-mainline-previous PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Etuxinvader/+archive/ubuntu/lts-mainline-previous)
- [tuxinvader's lts-mainline PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Etuxinvader/+archive/ubuntu/lts-mainline)

**Tip**: To see all available linux packages for your chosen series / version range, after messing with PPAs and maybe Debian backports, xanmod etc (as I have) do something like

```
apt update
printf '%s\0' linux-{image-unsigned,headers,modules}-5.10.{32..40} |
  xargs -0 -n 1 apt-cache pkgnames | LC_ALL=C sort | less
```

---

Hopefully this problem will go away. But let's face it, depending on the whims of the "kernel mainline PPA" (or whoever is behind it, I still don't understand **how these developers can be reached**) for binaries has not been a pleasant experience.

Comment: The next HWE kernel with *focal* will be 5.11 (20.04.3) which is what I would have opted to stick to (ie. HWE proposed kernels) but I haven't monitored how closely that is to being ready (*it's still a bit far off to worry about QA-testing it yet; as it's been stable on hirsute for some time which is where all recent focus has been*)

Comment: Oh gosh. That is a huge problem for me. I had not yet got around to installing mainline kernel 5.12 on my main 20.04 test server, and yes get the issue you mention. kernel 5.12-rc6 was fine. Darn.

Comment: I'm using the mainline kernel 5.11.16 with ubuntu 20.04. But from the kernel 5.11.17 it required libc >= 2.33. Hopefully they will revert this change.

Comment: Hopefully, it seems completely gratuitous. I've tried 5.11.17 too.

Comment: I just opened a bug on Mainline here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/umkl/+bug/1927024

Comment: FYI: I've added PPAs for 5.10.x and 5.11.x. https://launchpad.net/~tuxinvader/+archive/ubuntu/lts-mainline-longterm and https://launchpad.net/~tuxinvader/+archive/ubuntu/lts-mainline-previous

Comment: PPAs included in answer

Comment: @TuxInvader unfortunately your packages linux-headers* do not contain Makefile required for dkms

Comment: @sercxjo, perhaps open an issue on the project page? https://github.com/TuxInvader/focal-mainline-builder/issues

Comment: @sercxjo - The linux-headers issue is fixed. Someone opened an issue on github yesterday (as suggested by @usretc). DKMS should work fine now. I've also added a metapackage which will make it easier to get updates and avoid needing to install each point release manually.

Comment: @TuxInvader Thanks for the fix and for the metapackage!

Comment: @tuxinvader I ran into similar issue on Ubuntu MATE 21.04 while trying to install kernel 5.14.3. Any way out of this error? `dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-headers-5.14.3-051403-generic: linux-headers-5.14.3-051403-generic depends on libc6 (>= 2.34); however: Version of libc6:amd64 on system is 2.33-0ubuntu5`. Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can stay with LTS, but you will need to [compile the mainline kernels yourself](https://askubuntu.com/questions/718381/how-to-compile-and-install-custom-mainline-kernel/718662#718662) to overcome the new dependency issue.

The mainline compiler version used seems to have just changed:

```
doug@s19:~/temp-k-git/linux$ scripts/diffconfig .config-5.12.0-051200rc6-lowlatency .config-5.12.0-051200-lowlatency
 CC_VERSION_TEXT "gcc (Ubuntu 10.2.0-13ubuntu1) 10.2.0" -> "gcc (Ubuntu 10.3.0-1ubuntu1) 10.3.0"
 GCC_VERSION 100200 -> 100300
 LD_VERSION 23501 -> 23601
+DEBUG_INFO_BTF_MODULES y
+PAHOLE_HAS_SPLIT_BTF y
```

But if I just take the Ubuntu kernel configuration and compile myself, on my main 20.04 test server, it installs fine. I.E. the dependency is a function of the compiler version used not the kernel source code.

Not really relevant but here is the config difference for what I compiled:

```
doug@s19:~/temp-k-git/linux$ scripts/diffconfig .config-5.12.0-051200-lowlatency .config
-DEBUG_INFO_BTF y
-DEBUG_INFO_BTF_MODULES y
-DEBUG_INFO_COMPRESSED n
-DEBUG_INFO_DWARF4 y
-DEBUG_INFO_DWARF_TOOLCHAIN_DEFAULT n
-DEBUG_INFO_REDUCED n
-DEBUG_INFO_SPLIT n
-GDB_SCRIPTS y
-PAHOLE_HAS_SPLIT_BTF y
 CC_VERSION_TEXT "gcc (Ubuntu 10.3.0-1ubuntu1) 10.3.0" -> "gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0"
 DEBUG_INFO y -> n
 GCC_VERSION 100300 -> 90300
 LD_VERSION 23601 -> 23400
 SYSTEM_TRUSTED_KEYS "debian/canonical-certs.pem" -> ""
```

Comment: It's also possible that the gcc change was inadvertent and they might revert it, I think I've seen that happen in the past

Comment: Doug, good find, there's so much outdated howto advice for Ubuntu out there that I essentially gave up a while ago. It might also be possible to backport to a PPA, though I remember with kernel packages it's not that easy

Comment: Given that for many bugs on Launchpad there is a request to "try the latest mainline kernel" it seem likely that it will be made to work, either by compiler reversion or libc update.

Answer (score 7):

I was able to install 5.12 on Ubuntu 20.04 with `libc6` 2.31 using the mentioned ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tuxinvader/lts-mainline

sudo apt install linux-image-unsigned-5.12.4-051204-generic linux-modules-5.12.4-051204-generic linux-headers-5.12.4-051204-generic
```

Comment: Good. There are now also PPAs for 5.10 / 5.11 (see comments, answer needs updating)

Comment: Thanks @usretc for keeping the question updated. It was much easier to find a work around.

Answer (score 6):

Here is how i made dkms modules generated with kernel 5.11.18 from ubuntu mainline-kernel.
I run Linux Mint 20.1 Cinnamon and use nvidia-driver-460 version 460.73.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 in dkms.
The gcc I use is version 10.3.
Everything worked fine with ver 5.11.16-generic but stopped when i tried 5.11.18.
So I tried to find the problem why dkms did not compiled the kernel modules.
This is what I did:

1. Installed kernel 5.11.18-generic
2. Found that in kernel headers program fixdep relates to glibc 2.33
3. Found that in kernel headers program modpost relates to glibc 2.33
4. Replaced /lib/modules/5.11.18-generic/build/scripts/basic/fixdep with the one in 5.11.16
5. Replaced /lib/modules/5.11.18-generic/build/scripts/mod/modpost with the one in 5.11.16
6. Ran dkms against kernel 5.11.18  (/usr/lib/dkms/dkms_autoinstaller start 5.11.18-051118-generic)
7. Successfully generated nvidia kernel modules.
   Rebooted and it works ok.
   Even tried the same with kernel 5.12.1 and it worked.

Hope this helps.

Comment: upvoted, good for you, but it seems like this hack is the answer to another question :)

Comment: super useful tip.  thanks!

Comment: This approach no longer works with the latest kernel. I'm getting `ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-5.14.1-051401-generic is not supported`

Answer (score 0):

Another easy option to stay with 5.10, without compiling, seems to be to use a custom kernel. Like `xanmod`. The thing is, they don't seem to put much effort into "performance" improvements for the older LTS series, so I *think* one might be getting a pretty standard kernel. For example this is the log for [xanmod 5.10.35](https://dl.xanmod.org/changelog/5.10/ChangeLog-5.10.35-xanmod1).