# Ubuntu 20.04 and kernel 5.13.0-051300-generic: how to install the headers and libc6

Tags: 20.04, kernel, linux-headers

I recently upgraded the kernel to version `5.13.0-051300-generic` on my Tuxedo laptop equipped with Ubuntu 20.04. I am now trying to install the headers `linux-headers-5.13.0-051300-generic_5.13.0-051300.202106272333_amd64.deb`. If I try to do so with the command `sudo apt install ./linux-headers-5.13.0-051300-generic_5.13.0-051300.202106272333_amd64.deb`, I get the following error message:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-headers-5.13.0-051300-generic : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.33) but 2.31-0ubuntu9.3 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I then tried to install `libc6_2.33-0ubuntu5_amd64.deb` with the same command but get the following:

```
...
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libc6
WARNING: The following essential packages will be removed.
This should NOT be done unless you know exactly what you are doing!
  libc-bin
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 68 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/2,690 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2,034 MB disk space will be freed.
You are about to do something potentially harmful.
To continue type in the phrase 'Yes, do as I say!'
```

To which I stopped since I don't know what I'm doing exactly. I also tried the command `sudo dpkg -i libc6_2.33-0ubuntu5_amd64.deb`, and got the following:

```
dpkg: regarding libc6_2.33-0ubuntu5_amd64.deb containing libc6:amd64:
 libc6:amd64 breaks fakeroot (<< 1.25.3-1.1ubuntu2~)
  fakeroot (version 1.24-1) is present and installed.

dpkg: error processing archive libc6_2.33-0ubuntu5_amd64.deb (--install):
 installing libc6:amd64 would break fakeroot, and
 deconfiguration is not permitted (--auto-deconfigure might help)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libc6_2.33-0ubuntu5_amd64.deb
```

I then tried to upgrade `libfakeroot` using the `.deb` file and `GDebi` (I also tried to install `libc6` with this tool but the `Install` button is greyed out): if I check from the terminal the version of this library with `apt-cache policy fakeroot` I get `Installed: 1.24-1` but if I check with `sudo apt install ./libfakeroot_1.25.3-1.1_amd64.deb` I get:

```
Note, selecting 'libfakeroot' instead of './libfakeroot_1.25.3-1.1_amd64.deb'
libfakeroot is already the newest version (1.25.3-1.1).
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

EDIT 1
The result of `uname -a; ls /boot; apt-cache policy linux-headers-5.13.0-051300-generic linux-image-generic libc6 libc-bin libfakeroot` is the following:

```
Linux lorenzo-InfinityBookS 5.13.0-051300-generic #202106272333 SMP Sun Jun 27 23:36:43 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
config-5.13.0-051300-generic  grub                              initrd.img-5.8.0-59-generic  System.map-5.13.0-051300-generic  vmlinuz-5.13.0-051300-generic
config-5.4.0-77-generic       initrd.img                        initrd.img.old               System.map-5.4.0-77-generic       vmlinuz-5.4.0-77-generic
config-5.8.0-55-generic       initrd.img-5.13.0-051300-generic  memtest86+.bin               System.map-5.8.0-55-generic       vmlinuz-5.8.0-55-generic
config-5.8.0-59-generic       initrd.img-5.4.0-77-generic       memtest86+.elf               System.map-5.8.0-59-generic       vmlinuz-5.8.0-59-generic
efi                           initrd.img-5.8.0-55-generic       memtest86+_multiboot.bin     vmlinuz                           vmlinuz.old
linux-headers-5.13.0-051300-generic:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
linux-image-generic:
  Installed: 5.4.0.77.80
  Candidate: 5.4.0.77.80
  Version table:
 *** 5.4.0.77.80 500
        500 http://mirrors.tuxedocomputers.com/ubuntu/mirror/security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://mirrors.tuxedocomputers.com/ubuntu/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     5.4.0.26.32 500
        500 http://mirrors.tuxedocomputers.com/ubuntu/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
libc6:
  Installed: 2.31-0ubuntu9.3
  Candidate: 2.31-0ubuntu9.3
  Version table:
 *** 2.31-0ubuntu9.3 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.31-0ubuntu9.2 500
        500 http://mirrors.tuxedocomputers.com/ubuntu/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
     2.31-0ubuntu9 500
        500 http://mirrors.tuxedocomputers.com/ubuntu/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
libc-bin:
  Installed: 2.31-0ubuntu9.3
  Candidate: 2.31-0ubuntu9.3
  Version table:
 *** 2.31-0ubuntu9.3 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.31-0ubuntu9.2 500
        500 http://mirrors.tuxedocomputers.com/ubuntu/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
     2.31-0ubuntu9 500
        500 http://mirrors.tuxedocomputers.com/ubuntu/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
libfakeroot:
  Installed: 1.25.3-1.1
  Candidate: 1.25.3-1.1
  Version table:
 *** 1.25.3-1.1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.24-1 500
        500 http://mirrors.tuxedocomputers.com/ubuntu/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: You have strange package versions in your question. Please clarify them. Edit your question to add the following `uname -a; ls /boot; apt-cache policy linux-headers-5.13.0-051300-generic linux-image-generic libc6 libc-bin libfakeroot` .

Comment: "sudo apt install ./linux-headers-5.13.0-051300-generic_5.13.0-051300.202106272333_amd64.deb" Is the package already downloaded to your system? Please try: `sudo dpkg -i linux-headers*.deb`

Comment: Did you have any problems with packages previously? Does tuxedo provide special packages? If no, I would recommend to use default normal Ubuntu mirrors like archive.ubuntu.com . How did you installed kernel at version 5.13.0-051300-generic  and why?

Comment: @N0rbert Tuxedo recommends installing a package of theirs and I guess after installing it these mirrors were added... I haven't had any issue before.

Comment: @N0rbert I installed by downloading the .deb file if I remember correctly. Because I am having some issues installing a driver for a Ethernet-USB adapter.

Comment: What is the output for `dpkg -S /boot/vmlinuz-5.13.0-051300-generic`?

Comment: linux-image-unsigned-5.13.0-051300-generic: /boot/vmlinuz-5.13.0-051300-generic

Comment: And then `apt-cache policy linux-image-unsigned-5.13.0-051300-generic`

Comment: linux-image-unsigned-5.13.0-051300-generic:
  Installed: 5.13.0-051300.202106272333
  Candidate: 5.13.0-051300.202106272333
  Version table:
 *** 5.13.0-051300.202106272333 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127405/discussion-between-n0rbert-and-wrong-path).

Comment: early kernel 5.12.0 had same dependency `libc6 (>= 2.33)` which was removed in subsequent kernel releases.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At first we need to revert packages to their default versions from Ubuntu 20.04 LTS repository:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libc6=2.31-0ubuntu9.2 libc-bin=2.31-0ubuntu9.2
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libfakeroot=1.24-1
```

Then we need to remove just installed 5.13 kernel as its headers depend on newer libc6 which is not available for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Use command below:

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-headers-5.13.0-051300 linux-image-unsigned-5.13.0-051300-generic linux-modules-5.13.0-051300-generic
```

About original USB-Ethernet problem with TP Link U300 I see that it is based on Realtek RTL8153. This chip is supported at least by `linux-firmware` [package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=hirsute&arch=any&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=RTL8153). But it hard to give complete instruction without the output `journalctl -f` and `lsusb`, `lsusb -t`.

Comment: So is it that we cannot install 5.13 on 20.04 altogether?

Comment: Kernels from the mainline kernel ppa are not compatible with 20.04 anymore, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1334633/mainline-kernel-now-depends-on-libc6-2-33-non-installable-in-focal. If you need 5.13 there's now a version in the official repo called linux-image-oem-20.04c

Comment: Bug in kernel 5.13 and AMD APUs https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-hwe-5.13/+bug/1958519