# Compiling custom kernel

Tags: 20.04, kernel, compiling, development, ubuntu-drivers

I am interested in compiling a custom kernel in Ubuntu 20.04 so I can use the fingerprint scanner in my hp envy x360. Also I want to learn how to learn the process. Where do I start? How difficult is it? Any pointers and/or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/718381/how-to-compile-and-install-custom-mainline-kernel/718662#718662)

Answer (score 1):

From memory:

- Log in as root.
- Download the kernel sources from [kernel.org](https://www.kernel.org/) and uncompress them to `/usr/src/`.
- Open a shell in the directory you just unpacked and run:

  ```
  make oldconfig && \
  make xconfig && \
  make && \
  make modules && \
  make install && \
  make modules_install
  ```
- Edit your grub configuration and reboot.

If you're not running X then change `make xconfig` to `make menuconfig` or `make config`.

If you want things to go a bit quicker, change `make` to `make -j4` to run 4 tasks in parallel (change 4 to the number of cores your machine has).  The same applies to the `make modules` command.

Comment: How hard would it be to create linux drivers for my hardware that is not supported yet?

Comment: If there is no Linux driver currently available (in-kernel or otherwise) then I'd say it would likely be very difficult (especially if you have never written a kernel driver before).  In the end it boils down to whether hardware documentation/sample code is available.  I was in a similar situation as you with trying to set up a fingerprint scanner on a Sony laptop.  Since the manufacturer/sensor vendor withheld most of the technical data regarding the scanner the problem ended up being intractable.