# Fail to compile linux kernel after 5.13

Tags: compiling

I've successfully compiled linux source and built into `.deb` few months ago. The process roughly like:

1. copy existed config file into current folder (such as: cp /boot/config-xxxxx-generic .config)
2. make menuconfig
3. make -j4 deb-pkg LOCALVERSION=-custom

.... then it takes long time to compile

Recently, I fail at step 3. The error message shows:

```
make[2]: *** [debian/rules:7: build-arch] Error2
dpkg-buildpackage: error: debian/rules binary subprocess returned exit status 2
make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.package:77: deb-pkg] Error 2
```

I've found some similar issues and indicating that problem is at config file. I also tried generate config file by `make oldconfig` but still failed.

Anyone know how to solve it?

PS1. In my fuzzy memory, several months ago, I need to disable something in `.config` to build it successfully. I'm not sure what I exactly mask and is this associated with the problem.

PS2. config file I copied is pretty close to 5.13

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Oh, sorry for missing information, I'm using Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: It has been a lot more than a few months that "deb-pkg" has not worked. Try this: `make -j4 olddefconfig bindeb-pkg LOCALVERSION=-custom`. see also [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/718381/how-to-compile-and-install-custom-mainline-kernel/718662#718662).

Comment: @DougSmythies, really appreciate about your reference, I'll try it later. The tutorial I saw using deb-pkg is several years ago but it seems ok for me several months ago.

Comment: @DougSmythies, I follow your command, the error message is same. By `make olddefconfig`, I get four warning messages such as symbol value 'm' invalid for xxxx <- did this matter?

Comment: I think this message only hints there might be some errors occur before it. Yes, I miss some error before. Anyway, thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: Sometimes, not often, I have to do a `make clean` before a new compile.