# How to compile kernel 5.14.1 from kernel.org in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: kernel, compiling

I have Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS where i want to run my own kernel, so I did :

Kernel from https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v5.x/linux-5.14.1.tar.xz

```
make -j 3 allmodconfig
make -j 3 bzImage
make -j 3 modules
sudo make -j 3 modules_install
sudo make install
```

in recovery mode, the kernel panics in a softlockup in normal mode, the kernel also does not boot the root file system is lvm encrypted....

How to fix this ?

Comment: Can you boot with another kernel from the advanced options in the grub screen?

Comment: onlyl with the standard  ubuntu kernel

Comment: So boot with the working kernel, and remove the faulty ones.

Comment: actually i wanted to know why the kernel.org kernel does not boot, and fix that

Comment: Then please edit your question appropriately with which exact kernel you tried to install.

Comment: I added a link to the kernel source

Comment: You can download .deb packages of these kernels from https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.14.1/ (and install them in your own risk -- there are reasons the Ubuntu kernel team did not release them as updates yet).

Comment: Why do you want to upgrade the kernel? Does something not work correctly?

Comment: Pentium silver sound  does not work and for security reasons, and simply the philosophy, that the kernel.org kernel should work like this / so for testing resons

Comment: *Pentium silver sound does not work* -- You can ask a new question about that and *for security reasons* -- The existing kernels are regularly patched for  security. *kernel.org kernel should work like this* - You should edit your question to specify that you want to build a kernel.org kernel and ask how to do it.

Comment: Try following this [compile/install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/718381/how-to-compile-and-install-custom-mainline-kernel/718662#718662) method.