# How can I get MEDIATEK Corp. Device 7961 to work?

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless

I started out on Ubuntu 20.04

I wasn't able to install the wireless network card driver (for both Wifi and Bluetooth).

```
sudo lshw -C network
```

Output:

```
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
   description: Network controller
   product: MEDIATEK Corp.
   vendor: MEDIATEK Corp.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:2d:00.0
   version: 00
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pciexpress msi pm cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: iomemory:610-60f iomemory:610-60f iomemory:610-60f memory:612c100000-612c1fffff memory:612c200000-612c203fff memory:612c204000-612c204fff
```

Command: `rfkill list all`

Output

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

Command: `sudo lspci`

```
...
0000:2d:00.0 Network controller: MEDIATEK Corp. Device 7961
0000:2e:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
...
```

Command `sudo lsusb`

Output:

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 322e:202c Sonix Technology Co., Ltd. USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0b05:1910 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. TUF GAMING M3
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 13d3:3563 IMC Networks Wireless_Device
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I've installed Ubuntu 21.04 and upgrading my kernel to 5.12. I installed the network driver and I have got the wifi to work somewhat (randomly sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't) but the Bluetooth still doesn't work.

I've tried to install kernel version 5.15 following [this article](https://sypalo.com/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu), but after I finish downloading the kernel and I run the command `sudo dpkg -i *.deb` I get this error:

```
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-5.15.0-051500rc3.
(Reading database ... 202480 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack linux-headers-5.15.0-051500rc3_5.15.0-051500rc3.202109262230_all.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-5.15.0-051500rc3 (5.15.0-051500rc3.202109262230) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-5.15.0-051500rc3-generic.
Preparing to unpack linux-headers-5.15.0-051500rc3-generic_5.15.0-051500rc3.202109262230_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-5.15.0-051500rc3-generic (5.15.0-051500rc3.202109262230) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-image-unsigned-5.15.0-051500rc3-generic.
Preparing to unpack linux-image-unsigned-5.15.0-051500rc3-generic_5.15.0-051500rc3.202109262230_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-unsigned-5.15.0-051500rc3-generic (5.15.0-051500rc3.202109262230) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-modules-5.15.0-051500rc3-generic.
Preparing to unpack linux-modules-5.15.0-051500rc3-generic_5.15.0-051500rc3.202109262230_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-modules-5.15.0-051500rc3-generic (5.15.0-051500rc3.202109262230) ...
Setting up linux-headers-5.15.0-051500rc3 (5.15.0-051500rc3.202109262230) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-headers-5.15.0-051500rc3-generic:
 linux-headers-5.15.0-051500rc3-generic depends on libc6 (>= 2.34); however:
  Version of libc6:amd64 on system is 2.33-0ubuntu5.

dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-5.15.0-051500rc3-generic (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up linux-image-unsigned-5.15.0-051500rc3-generic (5.15.0-051500rc3.202109262230) ...
I: /boot/vmlinuz.old is now a symlink to vmlinuz-5.11.0-37-generic
I: /boot/initrd.img.old is now a symlink to initrd.img-5.11.0-37-generic
I: /boot/vmlinuz is now a symlink to vmlinuz-5.15.0-051500rc3-generic
I: /boot/initrd.img is now a symlink to initrd.img-5.15.0-051500rc3-generic
Setting up linux-modules-5.15.0-051500rc3-generic (5.15.0-051500rc3.202109262230) ...
Processing triggers for linux-image-unsigned-5.15.0-051500rc3-generic (5.15.0-051500rc3.202109262230) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-051500rc3-generic
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-051500rc3-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-051500rc3-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.11.0-37-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-37-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.11.0-16-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-16-generic
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/nvme0n1p1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings
done
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-headers-5.15.0-051500rc3-generic
```

How can I get this wireless card to work properly?

Comment: see [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1926938). You can also compile it yourself, see [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/718381/how-to-compile-and-install-custom-mainline-kernel/718662#718662). Also, I think you'll find the kernel actually works fine.

Comment: This version of Ubuntu does not have `libc6 2.34` that's why installation of this kernel fails.

Comment: @matigo thank so i install ubuntu 21.04, update my kernal to 5.14, try to reinstall netword driver and i got the wifi to work but bluetooth still don't any idea?

Comment: Hai all I got a solution for this- https://askubuntu.com/questions/1380400/no-wifi-adapter-found-on-ubuntu-20-04-3-lts. I think module is not properly added in the kernel. Hope they will update the kernel soon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't seem to get kernel 5.15 to work so I have to change to 5.14

Solve by disabling secure boot and changing to kernel 5.14.9

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cappelikan/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mainline
```

Open mainline and then select `5.14.9`. Click install. Then restart and boot to boot manager and disable secure boot.

Comment: Maybe edit your question to something like "How to use kernel 5.14 in Ubuntu 21.04?"

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi I feel the second question was an X-Y problem so I merged it into the first one

Comment: @Zanna I did not know moderators can merge questions :-)

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi :D now you know! :)