# No wifi adapter found on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Tags: drivers, wireless, 20.04

I have found a lots of answers of this question, but none of these worked for me. This problem occurred after a fresh installation on my MSI modern 15 (Ryzen 5 5500U) laptop.

Output of `sudo lshw -C network` command :

```
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: MEDIATEK Corp.
       vendor: MEDIATEK Corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:e0300000-e03fffff memory:e0400000-e0403fff memory:e0404000-e0404fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@3:2
       logical name: usb0
       serial: f6:2d:03:39:54:21
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=5.11.0-41-generic firmware=RNDIS device link=yes multicast=yes
```

Output of 'lspci' command

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Root Complex
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir IOMMU
00:01.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:01.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe GPP Bridge
00:01.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe GPP Bridge
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:02.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe GPP Bridge
00:08.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:08.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Internal PCIe GPP Bridge to Bus
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 51)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 51)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 5
00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 6
00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 7
01:00.0 Network controller: MEDIATEK Corp. Device 0608
02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
03:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Micron Technology Inc Device 5404 (rev 03)
04:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 164c (rev c2)
04:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 1637
04:00.2 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) Platform Security Processor
04:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir USB 3.1
04:00.4 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir USB 3.1
04:00.5 Multimedia controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor (rev 01)
04:00.6 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller
```

Output of `lspci -vvnn | grep -A 9 Network` command :

```
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: MEDIATEK Corp. Device [14c3:0608]
    Subsystem: MEDIATEK Corp. Device [14c3:0608]
    Control: I/O- Mem- BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 255
    Region 0: Memory at e0300000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [disabled] [size=1M]
    Region 2: Memory at e0400000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [disabled] [size=16K]
    Region 4: Memory at e0404000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [disabled] [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
```

Output of `modinfo mt7921e | grep alias` command :

```
alias:          pci:v000014C3d00007961sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
```

For your information : I disabled the secure boot & fast boot options when installing, as many people have faced problems like 'no wifi adapter found' by enabling them.

It will be really helpful for me, if any of you guys can tell me what Can I do now ?

Update : Removed the incorrect Broadcom Driver (`Kernel modules: wl` is gone from `lspci -vvnn` command)

Update2 : I have followed the answer given by chili555 accordingly, and phew... ! that worked. Thank you awesome people.

Comment: Try this instead `lspci -vvnn | grep -A 9 Network`

Comment: @darth_epoxy Tried this , output has been added

Comment: Try kicking the module in the guts `sudo modprobe -r wl && sudo modprobe wl` or someone on here might be able to help us confirm what firmware is requred for your device 14c3:0608 and we can check if that is installed

Comment: modprobe command didn't make any difference.   btw, Is it probable that The user manual will contain required firmware name ?  I am searching on that, did't find any though .

Comment: @darth_epoxy `wl` module is not related to this adapter. It is a Broadcom driver. There is no reason to have it installed at all.

Comment: Is the driver mt7921e present? Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `modinfo mt7921e | grep alias` Also, please remove the incorrect Broadcom driver: `sudo apt purge bcmwl-kernel-source` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 I have updated the question accordingly.

Comment: Please try these terminal commands and tell us if your wireless springs to life. If so, I will propose a permanent solution. `sudo modprobe mt7921e` and: `sudo echo 14c3 0608 > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/mt7921e/new_id`

Comment: I didn't have the write permission, so I had to use chmod command. But yes , this is working.

Comment: Please tell us what you used chmod on. It probably needs to be repaired. `history | grep chmod`

Comment: Please try https://askubuntu.com/a/1377785/300665

Comment: @Arnob Saha you should feel honoured, attracting the attention of pilot and chilli, they are legends.

Comment: @darth_epoxy Obviously, I am honoured. Their profile says, These guys are boss on this field.  I have to say that this is really an awesome community.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> MEDIATEK Corp. Device [14c3:0608]

This specific pci.id has recently been added to the aliases of the driver mt7921e. Reference: https://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-wireless/msg217303.html

Until this patch reaches a standard Ubuntu kernel, we may, as you've proven, add the pci.id with a udev action. From the terminal:

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/mt7921e.conf
```

Add a single line to this new file:

```
alias pci:v000014C3d00000608sv*sd*bc*sc*i* mt7921e
```

Proofread carefully. Save (Ctrl+o followed by Enter) and exit (Ctrl+x followed by Enter) the text editor nano.

Next, do:

```
sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/99-mt7921e.rules
```

Add a single line:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="drivers", DEVPATH=="/bus/pci/drivers/mt7921e", ATTR{new_id}="14c3 0608"
```

Proofread carefully, save and exit as above.

Your wireless should now work as expected. To confirm, please test with a reboot.

Comment: You asked me about what I have used in  "chmod" commad on. To inform you...  I first tried ` sudo chmod u+w /sys/bus/pci/drivers/mt7921e/new_id` , It didn't work. Then I directly gave all the permission without bothering with it `sudo chmod **777** /sys/bus/pci/drivers/mt7921e/new_id`.   Thanks a lot man for your time & answer.

Comment: It might or might not harm anything to do 777, but let's be safe and return it to its default state: `sudo chmod 0200 /sys/bus/pci/drivers/mt7921e/new_id` If my answer has been helpful, please accept it: https://askubuntu.com/tour

Comment: By running `ls -la` command on that directory , I have found that ...This file permission was somehow automatically recovered !!  Didn't need to  run `chmod` again.

Comment: Hi @chili555 . Hope you are well.  Your solution was working perfectly. But today my pc got hanged, & I gave a forced shutdown. After that, I am running with a new problem. It says, "Activation of Network connection failed"!  I have tried.. 1) Disable & enable network connection 2)Disable fastBoot 3)checked the edited files(as your answer) if they are ok. 3)Disable 'auto connect' to my wifi 4) Restart network manager by `sudo systemctl restart network-manager.service` and `sudo /etc/init.d/network-manager force-reload`. But none of them worked.  Can you please help me in this strange issue ?

Comment: Please start a new question as this is a new, different issue. Include a link to this question. I will be very glad to help.

Comment: I didn't start a new question, because this two are inter-connected. However, I have tried multiple solutions from ask Ubuntu on this issue. And the Good thing is .. One of them just worked.  I had to reinstall the `network-manager` package.   So, no need to make a new question-thread now.    By the way, Thanks for your response.