# Network unclaimed on Ubuntu 20.04.03

Tags: networking, 20.04, wireless

I can't use wireless network(WiFi). I can't install WiFi drivers

```
lspci -v | grep -i network
03:00.0 Network controller: MEDIATEK Corp. Device 7961

sudo lshw -C network
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 15
       serial: 7c:8a:e1:a4:bf:ea
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.11.0-27-generic firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:42 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:d1704000-d1704fff memory:d1700000-d1703fff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: MEDIATEK Corp.
       vendor: MEDIATEK Corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: iomemory:fc0-fbf iomemory:fc0-fbf iomemory:fc0-fbf memory:fc02000000-fc020fffff memory:fc02100000-fc02103fff memory:fc02104000-fc02104fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       bus info: usb@1:2
       logical name: enx00a0c6000000
       serial: 00:a0:c6:00:00:00
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=5.11.0-27-generic firmware=RNDIS device ip=10.0.0.100 link=yes multicast=yes
```

I can't understand which drivers I have to install. RTL8111 or MEDIATEK 7961 for wifi. or upgrading kernel to 15 may solve this.

```
uname -r
5.11.0-27-generic
```

Comment: You have not given a reason that the wired connection is so bad.

Comment: Looks like my laptop lenovo idealad gaming 3 doesn't have a ethernet connector. I used WiFi adapter with USB. And this speed is awful for working. Anyway I need WiFi without USB connection. I don't know why it so slow

Comment: You need to clean up your question it does not say you do not have wired connection it says its slow or something. After reading this comment I am confused what you are doing. What is the the exact model of the laptop?

Comment: The thing is I don't have WiFi. I am using something called ethernet so ethernet or wired internet is slow. Ubuntu doesn't show WiFi icon.The model is 82K201D1RK

Comment: Your question is still unclear. Is your question how to install drivers for the wifi; or, is your question how to troubleshoot the slow ethernet connection? Please edit your question to ask one or the other. We will be happy to attempt to answer each but in two different questions. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: How to install WiFi drivers, question is updated

Comment: Please try this. I am not sure it will work for kernel version 5.11, however.https://askubuntu.com/questions/1380400/no-wifi-adapter-found-on-ubuntu-20-04-3-lts/1380495#1380495

Comment: Install updates, that should install the 5.13 kernel that supports that device

Comment: Sudo apt-get update? If I use ethernet I can wait a few hours or may be more. I give it a try. Is it possible to install ubuntu with kernel 5.13. I heard I can update ubuntu drivers by having ubuntu .iso.

Comment: @chili555 it doesn't help.

Comment: I don't think that having windows as first os can cause this error. I have a pc only ubuntu but there is no wifi driver too.

Comment: If you have a smartphone, connect to the wifi with phone and use USB tethering to the computer to install updates

Comment: Jeremy after a lot of time i updated my kernel and wifi appears. So you can answer on this question. I mark it as answer. I made auto update from 5.11 and it's says 5.13 now. Also I found ethernet connector on my laptop and internet connection became very fast

Answer (score -1):

after a lot of time of searching updating kernel fixed my issue. From 5.11 to 5.13. The instructions are here. Also with download third party options and download updates (while installing ubuntu) with connected ethernet also helped me with installing WiFi.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: What about later when that link does not work? Best ti include the info in the answer. You can have the link but have the info as well.

Comment: I added more description