# No Onboard Wifi Adapter Found After Hard Reset Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: networking, wireless, hardware

**EDIT/SOLUTION:** The problem didn't lie within Ubuntu, it lied within my power management/motherboard!

When booting up, the BIOS would give me a variety of error messages, but I decided to investigate one in particular today (summarized because I don't remember the exact error):

`"USB device not accepting address"`

Eventually when booting, not even my USB wireless adapter would work. So, I googled that error and [I found this extremely simple guide that said](https://paulphilippov.com/articles/how-to-fix-device-not-accepting-address-error) the cause is most likely hardware failure. I shut down my computer, unplugged all my USB devices,turned off the power switch and unplugged it, then waited 2 minutes. I then turned the computer back on and plugged everything back in, and voila it worked!

I will leave all my initial troubleshooting below in order to serve as documentation/tags in case anyone else runs into this issue in the future.

---

---

---

I am submitting this question because my previously-recognized **onboard** Wifi Adapter is no longer being found after a hard power-off. Sometimes, Ubuntu does not load when I wake up my PC from sleep, and my computer simply gives me a blank screen. In these cases, I do a hard power-off by **pressing and holding my power button for 5 seconds**. After the latest time I did this, I logged on to my computer and Ubuntu would not connect to the internet (wifi icon in upper right was gone), and I found no network hardware when I went into wifi settings.

I found an old USB Wifi adapter that I was able to install the drivers for and which works on my PC, however it takes a few minutes to register when I boot up, and I'd rather just get my onboard wifi to be recognized again.

[I took a look at this issue which seemed very similar](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1380400/no-wifi-adapter-found-on-ubuntu-20-04-3-lts), and followed the steps within it (creating a new conf file and modifying a rules file), but this did not work to fix my issue.

I will provide software info below, please let me know if you need any more info or need me to run any commands. I know Ubuntu on an extremely elementary level, so I should be able to run any commands in terminal you ask of me.

Output of `sudo lshw -C network`   command :

```
 *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0c:00.0
       logical name: enp12s0
       version: 05
       serial: 74:56:3c:43:0c:15
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.19.0-32-generic firmware=rtl8125b-2_0.0.2 07/13/20 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:34 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:81800000-8180ffff memory:81810000-81813fff
  *-network
       description: Network controller
       product: MEDIATEK Corp.
       vendor: MEDIATEK Corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0d:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=mt7921e latency=0
       resources: iomemory:fc0-fbf irq:97 memory:fc02100000-fc021fffff memory:81900000-81907fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: d
       bus info: usb@1:3
       logical name: wlx0013eff6b9c8
       serial: 00:13:ef:f6:b9:c8
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl88x2bu driverversion=v5.13.1-20-gbd7c7eb9d.20210702_ firmware=30.20 ip=192.168.106.106 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11AC
```

Output of `lspci | grep -i net` command:

```
0c:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller (rev 05)
0d:00.0 Network controller: MEDIATEK Corp. Device 0616
```

Output of `modinfo mt7921e | grep alias` command :

```
alias:          pci:v000014C3d00000616sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014C3d00000608sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014C3d00007922sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014C3d00007961sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
```

I've already followed the steps in the above linked issue, and tried running the `modprobe mt7921e` command to automatically add drivers, however my onboard wifi is still not recognized.

Output of `rfkill list all` command:

```
1: phy2: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

In case you need my USB Wifi adapter info, here's the output of `lsusb`:

```
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:b812 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL88x2bu [AC1200 Techkey]
```

Output of `service NetworkManager status` :

```
● NetworkManager.service - Network Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2023-02-27 08:22:50 CST; 1 day 6h ago
       Docs: man:NetworkManager(8)
   Main PID: 1010 (NetworkManager)
      Tasks: 3 (limit: 37395)
     Memory: 13.0M
        CPU: 6.228s
     CGroup: /system.slice/NetworkManager.service
             └─1010 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

Feb 28 13:29:45 zeta NetworkManager[1010]: <info>  [1677612585.5108] device (tun0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Feb 28 13:29:45 zeta NetworkManager[1010]: <info>  [1677612585.5109] device (tun0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Feb 28 13:29:45 zeta NetworkManager[1010]: <info>  [1677612585.5110] device (tun0): Activation: successful, device activated.
Feb 28 13:31:37 zeta NetworkManager[1010]: <info>  [1677612697.3712] dhcp4 (wlx0013eff6b9c8): state changed new lease, address=192.168.106.106
Feb 28 14:01:37 zeta NetworkManager[1010]: <info>  [1677614497.3558] dhcp4 (wlx0013eff6b9c8): state changed new lease, address=192.168.106.106
Feb 28 14:31:37 zeta NetworkManager[1010]: <info>  [1677616297.3574] dhcp4 (wlx0013eff6b9c8): state changed new lease, address=192.168.106.106
Feb 28 15:01:37 zeta NetworkManager[1010]: <info>  [1677618097.3556] dhcp4 (wlx0013eff6b9c8): state changed new lease, address=192.168.106.106
Feb 28 15:07:00 zeta NetworkManager[1010]: <info>  [1677618420.6335] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Feb 28 15:07:01 zeta NetworkManager[1010]: <info>  [1677618421.0782] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Feb 28 15:10:06 zeta NetworkManager[1010]: <info>  [1677618606.4966] agent-manager: agent[712460a0b443d1cb,:1.95/org.gnome.Shell.NetworkAgent/1000]: agent registered
~
```

Output of `ip route`:

```
ip route
default via 192.168.106.1 dev wlx0013eff6b9c8 proto dhcp metric 600 
10.0.3.0/24 dev lxcbr0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.3.1 linkdown 
169.254.0.0/16 dev lxcbr0 scope link metric 1000 linkdown 
192.168.106.0/24 dev wlx0013eff6b9c8 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.106.106 metric 600
```

Output of `ip link`:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp12s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 74:56:3c:43:0c:15 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: lxcbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:16:3e:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: wlx0013eff6b9c8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:13:ef:f6:b9:c8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Output of `sudo dmesg | grep mt76`:

```
[49391.166058] Modules linked in: xt_addrtype xt_nat nft_masq bridge stp llc nft_chain_nat nf_nat nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 nvidia_uvm(PO) ip6t_REJECT nf_reject_ipv6 ipt_REJECT nf_reject_ipv4 xt_multiport xt_cgroup xt_mark xt_owner xt_tcpudp nft_compat nf_tables libcrc32c nfnetlink binder_linux joydev input_leds nvidia_drm(PO) snd_hda_codec_realtek binfmt_misc snd_hda_codec_generic nvidia_modeset(PO) ledtrig_audio snd_hda_codec_hdmi intel_rapl_msr snd_hda_intel intel_rapl_common amdgpu nvidia(PO) nls_iso8859_1 snd_intel_dspcfg snd_usb_audio snd_intel_sdw_acpi snd_hda_codec snd_usbmidi_lib snd_hda_core iommu_v2 mc snd_hwdep gpu_sched mt7921e snd_pcm drm_ttm_helper mt7921_common ttm snd_seq_midi drm_display_helper mt76_connac_lib snd_seq_midi_event edac_mce_amd cec mt76 snd_rawmidi kvm_amd 88x2bu(OE) rc_core snd_seq mac80211 drm_kms_helper snd_seq_device kvm i2c_algo_bit snd_timer fb_sys_fops crct10dif_pclmul syscopyarea snd ghash_clmulni_intel sysfillrect cfg80211 libarc4
```

**Any ideas on how I can further investigate this issue?**

Comment: Look at `service NetworkManager status`, `ip route;ip link`. Read `man ip ip-route ip-link`.

Comment: @waltinator I just added the outputs of those commands to my main post. From my understanding, the IP route shows the networking addresses used by the computer, and the IP link command shows the networking hardware, is that correct? In that case, it seems like my onboard PCI wireless is in an UNKNOWN status. However, I don't know what to do with that information/how to use ip-link to solve that.

Comment: May we see, in an edit: `sudo dmesg | grep mt76` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

Comment: @chili555 added to my post!

Comment: @waltinator it gives me a lot of info in one place! However, I don't have the technical know-how to really do anything with all that information. It also contains things like my wifi network name, so I may have to scrub the file of sensitive information first before I post it on here. Thank you for linking that though, I will add to my post tomorrow with the edited information :)

Comment: Power resets are normally 15-30 seconds of holding in the power button, or if you can remove all power (battery as well if possible, if not, 15-30 seconds) from the system then press the power button a few times without power.  Usually your computer manufacturer should have the info on how to do a hard power reset.

Comment: Hey @Terrance, the reason I included that point was just to show the preceding action I took before these issues occurred. My main issue is with my onboard network hardware not being used to connect to wifi.

Comment: Maybe try a hard power reset. It might help bring the Wi-Fi on the board back up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLUTION: The problem didn't lie within Ubuntu, it lied within my power management/motherboard!

When booting up, the BIOS would give me a variety of error messages, but I decided to investigate one in particular today (summarized because I don't remember the exact error):

"USB device not accepting address"

Eventually when booting, not even my USB wireless adapter would work. So, I googled that error and I found this extremely simple guide that said the cause is most likely hardware failure. I shut down my computer, unplugged all my USB devices,turned off the power switch and unplugged it, then waited 2 minutes. I then turned the computer back on and plugged everything back in, and voila it worked!

I will leave all my initial troubleshooting intact in order to serve as documentation/tags in case anyone else runs into this issue in the future.