# ubuntu 22.04 / Mediatek mt7921e network card "No wifi adapter found"

Tags: networking, 20.04, wireless

I have just installed ubuntu 20.04 (alone, no dual boot) on a hp elitebook laptop (which is new).
Wifi worked for a few hours, but then stopped working ("No wifi adapter found"). Ethernet is working fine though.

I have tried several options to resolve it (especially [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1380400/no-wifi-adapter-found-on-ubuntu-20-04-3-lts) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1380400/no-wifi-adapter-found-on-ubuntu-20-04-3-lts)), but none of them worked.
Secure boot and fast boot options are disabled.

**Output of `sudo lshw -C network`**

```
  *-network                 
   description: Ethernet interface
   produit: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   fabricant: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   identifiant matériel: 0
   information bus: pci@0000:01:00.0
   nom logique: enp1s0
   version: 15
   numéro de série: bc:0f:f3:72:ec:bd
   taille: 100Mbit/s
   capacité: 1Gbit/s
   bits: 64 bits
   horloge: 33MHz
   fonctionnalités: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration : autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=6.2.0-32-generic duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=140.77.152.15 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
   ressources : irq:56 portE/S:2000(taille=256) mémoire:fb704000-fb704fff mémoire:fb700000-fb703fff
*-network NON-RÉCLAMÉ
       description: Network controller
       produit: MEDIATEK Corp.
       fabricant: MEDIATEK Corp.
       identifiant matériel: 0
       information bus: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 00
       bits: 64 bits
       horloge: 33MHz
       fonctionnalités: pciexpress msi pm cap_list
       configuration : latency=0
       ressources : mémoire:fb500000-fb5fffff mémoire:fb600000-fb607fff
```

**Output of `lspci -nn`**

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne Root Complex [1022:1630]
00:00.2 IOMMU [0806]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne IOMMU [1022:1631]
00:01.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge [1022:1632]
00:01.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne PCIe GPP Bridge [1022:1634]
00:01.3 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne PCIe GPP Bridge [1022:1634]
00:02.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge [1022:1632]
00:02.4 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne PCIe GPP Bridge [1022:1634]
00:08.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge [1022:1632]
00:08.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Internal PCIe GPP Bridge to Bus [1022:1635]
00:14.0 SMBus [0c05]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller [1022:790b] (rev 51)
00:14.3 ISA bridge [0601]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge [1022:790e] (rev 51)
00:18.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 0 [1022:166a]
00:18.1 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 1 [1022:166b]
00:18.2 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 2 [1022:166c]
00:18.3 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 3 [1022:166d]
00:18.4 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 4 [1022:166e]
00:18.5 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 5 [1022:166f]
00:18.6 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 6 [1022:1670]
00:18.7 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 7 [1022:1671]
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: MEDIATEK Corp. Device [14c3:0616]
03:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: Sandisk Corp Device [15b7:5017] (rev 01)
04:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Barcelo [1002:15e7] (rev c6)
04:00.1 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Renoir Radeon High Definition Audio Controller [1002:1637]
04:00.2 Encryption controller [1080]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) Platform Security Processor [1022:15df]
04:00.3 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne USB 3.1 [1022:1639]
04:00.4 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne USB 3.1 [1022:1639]
04:00.5 Multimedia controller [0480]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor [1022:15e2] (rev 01)
04:00.6 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller [1022:15e3]
```

**Output of `lsmod | grep mt7921e`**

```
mt7921e                28672  0
mt7921_common         114688  1 mt7921e
mt76_connac_lib        90112  2 mt7921e,mt7921_common
mt76                  122880  3 mt7921e,mt7921_common,mt76_connac_lib
```

**Output of `cat /etc/modprobe.d/mt7921e.conf`**

```
alias pci:v000014C3d00000608xsv*sd*bc*sc*i* mt7921e
```

**Output of `cat /etc/udev/rules.d/99-mt7921e.rules`**

```
SUBSYSTEM=="drivers", DEVPATH=="/bus/pci/drivers/mt7921e", ATTR{new_id}="14c3 0608"
```

I have noticed that bluetooth isn't working either (i don't know if both problems can be linked).

I am far from being an expert, so any help is welcome. Thanks :)

**Update**

I updated to ubuntu 22.04, which did not fix the issue (kernel version is 6.2).

The init command of the driver seems to fail : output of `journalctl -b | grep -iE '02:00.0|mt7921e'`

```
sept. 06 08:39:52 camille-mmi kernel: pci 0000:02:00.0: [14c3:0616] type 00 class 0x028000
sept. 06 08:39:52 camille-mmi kernel: pci 0000:02:00.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0xfb500000-0xfb5fffff 64bit pref]
sept. 06 08:39:52 camille-mmi kernel: pci 0000:02:00.0: reg 0x18: [mem 0xfb600000-0xfb607fff 64bit]
sept. 06 08:39:52 camille-mmi kernel: pci 0000:02:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D3hot D3cold
sept. 06 08:39:52 camille-mmi kernel: pci 0000:02:00.0: Adding to iommu group 10
sept. 06 08:39:52 camille-mmi kernel: mt7921e 0000:02:00.0: ASIC revision: 79220010
sept. 06 08:39:52 camille-mmi systemd-udevd[325]: mt7921e: /etc/udev/rules.d/99-mt7921e.rules:1 Failed to write ATTR{/sys/bus/pci/drivers/mt7921e/new_id}, ignoring: File exists
sept. 06 08:39:55 camille-mmi kernel: mt7921e 0000:02:00.0: Message 00000010 (seq 1) timeout
sept. 06 08:39:55 camille-mmi kernel: mt7921e 0000:02:00.0: Failed to get patch semaphore
sept. 06 08:39:59 camille-mmi kernel: mt7921e 0000:02:00.0: Message 00000010 (seq 2) timeout
sept. 06 08:39:59 camille-mmi kernel: mt7921e 0000:02:00.0: Failed to get patch semaphore
sept. 06 08:40:02 camille-mmi kernel: mt7921e 0000:02:00.0: Message 00000010 (seq 3) timeout
sept. 06 08:40:02 camille-mmi kernel: mt7921e 0000:02:00.0: Failed to get patch semaphore
sept. 06 08:40:05 camille-mmi kernel: mt7921e 0000:02:00.0: Message 00000010 (seq 4) timeout
sept. 06 08:40:05 camille-mmi kernel: mt7921e 0000:02:00.0: Failed to get patch semaphore
sept. 06 08:40:09 camille-mmi kernel: mt7921e 0000:02:00.0: Message 00000010 (seq 5) timeout
sept. 06 08:40:09 camille-mmi kernel: mt7921e 0000:02:00.0: Failed to get patch semaphore
sept. 06 08:40:12 camille-mmi kernel: mt7921e 0000:02:00.0: Message 00000010 (seq 6) timeout
sept. 06 08:40:12 camille-mmi kernel: mt7921e 0000:02:00.0: Failed to get patch semaphore
sept. 06 08:40:15 camille-mmi kernel: mt7921e 0000:02:00.0: Message 00000010 (seq 7) timeout
sept. 06 08:40:15 camille-mmi kernel: mt7921e 0000:02:00.0: Failed to get patch semaphore
sept. 06 08:40:19 camille-mmi kernel: mt7921e 0000:02:00.0: Message 00000010 (seq 8) timeout
sept. 06 08:40:19 camille-mmi kernel: mt7921e 0000:02:00.0: Failed to get patch semaphore
sept. 06 08:40:22 camille-mmi kernel: mt7921e 0000:02:00.0: Message 00000010 (seq 9) timeout
sept. 06 08:40:22 camille-mmi kernel: mt7921e 0000:02:00.0: Failed to get patch semaphore
sept. 06 08:40:25 camille-mmi kernel: mt7921e 0000:02:00.0: Message 00000010 (seq 10) timeout
sept. 06 08:40:25 camille-mmi kernel: mt7921e 0000:02:00.0: Failed to get patch semaphore
sept. 06 08:40:26 camille-mmi kernel: mt7921e 0000:02:00.0: hardware init failed
```

**Update 2**
I updated my kernel to version 6.5.1, i still have the "No wifi adapter found" error, however the error messages changed :

```
camille@camille-mmi:~$ journalctl -b | grep -iE '02:00.0|mt7921e'
sept. 06 10:32:51 camille-mmi kernel: pci 0000:02:00.0: [14c3:0616] type 00 class 0x028000
sept. 06 10:32:51 camille-mmi kernel: pci 0000:02:00.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0xfb500000-0xfb5fffff 64bit pref]
sept. 06 10:32:51 camille-mmi kernel: pci 0000:02:00.0: reg 0x18: [mem 0xfb600000-0xfb607fff 64bit]
sept. 06 10:32:51 camille-mmi kernel: pci 0000:02:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D3hot D3cold
sept. 06 10:32:51 camille-mmi kernel: pci 0000:02:00.0: Adding to iommu group 10
sept. 06 10:32:53 camille-mmi systemd-udevd[379]: mt7921e: /etc/udev/rules.d/99-mt7921e.rules:1 Failed to write ATTR{/sys/bus/pci/drivers/mt7921e/new_id}, ignoring: File exists
sept. 06 10:32:55 camille-mmi kernel: mt7921e 0000:02:00.0: driver own failed
sept. 06 10:32:55 camille-mmi kernel: mt7921e: probe of 0000:02:00.0 failed with error -5
```

**Update 3**
It finally worked after the kernel update and switching off my computer, waiting a few minutes and turning it on again (instead of reboot).

Comment: Better append `lspci -nn` output

Comment: I just updated my question :)

Comment: Please edit to include results from terminal for `cat /etc/modprobe.d/mt7921e.conf; cat /etc/udev/rules.d/99-mt7921e.rules`

Comment: I just added it

Comment: You seem to be suffering from this bug: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/525c469e5de9bf7e53574396196e80fc716ac9eb. As a solution try updating your kernel to version 6.5

Comment: Try this: https://github.com/openwrt/mt76/issues/548#issuecomment-860083371

Comment: Ok, it worked... Thank you so much !

Comment: Is it reported as MT7922 in `lspci` now? If so I guess you should update the title

Comment: Yes, it hasn't changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following RA suggestions, i updated the kernel version and then powered off my computer and waited for a few minutes before turning it on again (instead of reboot).

Answer (score 0):

I tried many things from others topics in the web. No solution specific to a unique post worked for me.

I'm using a new laptop:

- Asus rog flow x13 GV302x
- AMD Ryzen 9 7940HS w/ Radeon 780M Graphics
- RTX 4060

I had the same output from `sudo lshw -C network` as @atik

and my Network Controller from `sudo lspci -nn` is :

`06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: MEDIATEK Corp. Device [14c3:0616]`

I just **find a way** to have a Network wifi adapter enabled and i'm now connected to internet.

First i decided to **install a fresh 22.04LTS version of Ubuntu** using a **dual boot** with a Windows 11.

Secondly i updated my kernel version as @atik did in his post:

```
$ uname -rms
Linux 6.5.1-060501-generic x86_64
```

**To install this version i used mainline kernels**

(ps: If ubuntu is still in the previous version, make sure to run via the "Advanced option for Ubuntu" and then choose the version you want to launch. **Make sure to disable fast boot and secure boot in the bios of your PC**)

Then, i tried to shutdown and boot the PC in this version of Kernel but it still "No wifi adapter found". So i tried to do what [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1380400/no-wifi-adapter-found-on-ubuntu-20-04-3-lts) said.

After creating and editing `sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/mt7921e.conf` with this line:

```
alias pci:v000014C3d00000608xsv*sd*bc*sc*i* mt7921e
```

and `sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/99-mt7921e.rules` with this line:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="drivers", DEVPATH=="/bus/pci/drivers/mt7921e", ATTR{new_id}="14c3 0608"
```

But after shutdown and boot Ubuntu, it still "No wifi adapter found".
Then i did many research on the web, and i find [this post](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2488997) who it's said **Shut it down, remove power cord and battery(if possible), then press and hold power key for 30 seconds. Put back together and boot**

I pressed my power button during 30 seconds and the pc reboot automatically. After thiss step, i just had my Wifi enabled, and it **succeed to connect to internet**.

when i re-run this command `sudo lswh -C network` i have now a new configuration part:

```
*-network                 
   description: Wireless interface
   product: MEDIATEK Corp.
   vendor: MEDIATEK Corp.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
   logical name: wlp6s0
   version: 00
   serial: 00:41:0e:bd:4b:ad
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pciexpress msi pm bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=mt7921e driverversion=6.5.1-060501-generic firmware=____000000-20221227123243 ip=192.168.1.92 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
```

I don't know if this can help some peoples, but I think that following these steps was **enough for me to solve my problem**, so please keep me informed if this is the case for you.

Answer (score 0):

replaced the mt7902 with an intel AX210 and... running out of the box with kernel 6.7.1 stable.

details:
before: https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=42b02a9d8e
now: https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=f9da9c2d2e

wlan/bt adapter details:
AX210.NGWG.NV
M.2 2230, BT 5.2, No vPro

regards
thomi