Wi-fi not showing up & Bluetooth not working - Ubuntu 24.04
I recently purchased a new ASUS laptop (ASUS VivoBook 15X K3504ZA-BQ094) and tried installing Ubuntu 24.04 (latest version on the Ubuntu website). During the installation, the connect to Wi-fi option was disabled and even after the installation, I don't have an option to connect to Wi-fi (it's missing in the menu from the upper-right corner).
When I try to turn on the Bluetooth from the upper-right corner menu, 3 dots (...) appear over the Bluetooth icon and nothing happens, and if I try to turn it on from the Settings page, the switch automatically turns off.
I connected a phone to the laptop to check for updates and it updated 400MB but nothing about wi-fi (still not showing). In Software Updater there are no more updates and in Software & Updates -> Additional drivers it says no additional drivers available.
Some commands and their results (if it helps):
lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3

0000:02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: MEDIATEK Corp. Device [14c3:7902]
DeviceName: WLAN
Subsystem: AzureWave Device [1a3b:5520]
10000:e0:06.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 12th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x4 Controller #0 [8086:464d] (rev 04)

nmcli device

DEVICE           TYPE      STATE                   CONNECTION        
lo               loopback  connected (externally)  lo

EDIT: command from comment
sudo lshw -C network

*-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: MEDIATEK Corp.
       vendor: MEDIATEK Corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff memory:6000000000-60000fffff memory:84000000-84007fff

The laptop came with No OS, and I'm not dual booting with Windows or anything, just trying to install a functional Ubuntu.
If there is anybody that can help me, thanks in advance!

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Certified laptops are Dell, HP and Lenovo. https://ubuntu.com/certified?q=&limit=20&category=Desktop&category=Laptop

@alphacoder001 Pls edit and add output of sudo lshw -C network to your question

@amar I added the result of the requested command

@alphacoder001 It seems it is the same as https://askubuntu.com/questions/1484787/ubuntu-22-04-mediatek-mt7921e-network-card-no-wifi-adapter-found you can try the  answer from vcheloudiakoff just the part about how to turn off

@amar tried it several times, didn't work

I hope someone else can help you otherwise the best bet is to buy a usb network adapter that has linux drivers.

Looks like a kerne issue, somebody over at archlinux had problems with the same card. https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=286981 there seems to be a kernel patch that might help you.

I had a similar issue. I fixed the wifi, but bluetooth still does not toggle on in the settings menu.
Step 1 Get network hardware info
lshw -C network

lspci -k | grep -i network -A 3


lspci -k | grep -i network -A 3
09:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6E(802.11ax) AX210/AX1675* 2x2 [Typhoon Peak] (rev 1a)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX210 160MHz
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
0a:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)

My network hardware was Intel Wi-Fi 6E AX210/AX1675 and my driver was iwlwifi, as you can see from above output. You will need the name of your driver so save this for later.
I tried updating the firmware
sudo apt update
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-firmware


to then reload the wifi module
sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi
sudo modprobe iwlwifi

It was not working so we used
dmesg | grep iwlwifi

Which showed that my system was searching for firmware files between vesrions 39-64. It was a long out put which showed iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-XX.ucode Where those two bold XX's were numbers between 39-64.
So we check on the firmware files...
ls /lib/firmware/ | grep iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0

iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-59.ucode.zst
iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-66.ucode.zst
iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-72.ucode.zst
iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-73.ucode.zst
iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-74.ucode.zst
iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-77.ucode.zst
iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-78.ucode.zst
iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-79.ucode.zst
iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-81.ucode.zst
iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-83.ucode.zst
iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-84.ucode.zst
iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-86.ucode.zst
iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0.pnvm.zst


Turns out the firmware files were not decompressed they were compressed in.zst format still.
You can decompress the firmwarefiles with
sudo apt install zstd
sudo zstd -d /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-*.zst

Now you can unload and reload the wifi driver
sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi
sudo modprobe iwlwifi

Restart network manager
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager.service

Then check and see if that resolved the issue
nmcli device wifi list


You should see a list of wifi networks in your area.
