# Building linux kernel - Incremental

Tags: compiling

How to perform an incremental build of `Ubuntu 22.04`'s Linux kernel. When build is done using `fakeroot debian/rules binary` it starts a fresh build.

Comment: what do you mean by "incremental"?

Comment: An incremental builds means without executing `make clean` as an early step in the compile, which Ubuntu does by default. An incremental compile only recompiles things that have changed. As such the compile can complete much much faster. It is all I ever use for mainline kernel compiles, but I have never figured out how to do it for Standard Ubuntu kernels. @Pilot6.

Comment: It doesn't do clean. You run `debian/rules clean` for that. You can look into the script.

Comment: @Pilot6 : O.K. All I know for certain is that the Ubuntu way always seemed to behave a like fresh, clean compile. My mainline compiles, detailed how to [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/718381/how-to-compile-and-install-custom-mainline-kernel/718662#718662) don't. Disclaimer: It has been many years since I have even attempted to compile the Ubuntu kernel.

Comment: I build kernels. It is fast anyway even with not super powerful CPU. I really never cared about that.

Comment: I get 19 minutes and 8 seconds for a clean build and 1 minute 4 seconds for an incremental build (minimal changes). I tried to follow the path of `debian/rules binary` build and got lost. I use "bindeb-pkg" in my make command line, and it doesn't call "clean". "deb-pkg" does call "clean". If I understand correctly, `debian/rules` uses "intdeb-pkg" which I had trouble following.