# Compiling Ubuntu 20.04 kernel with CONFIG_NO_HZ_FULL leads to multiple config errors

Tags: 20.04, package-management, kernel, compiling

I am following the steps on [Build Your Own Kernel](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel)

I got a stock kernel from Ubuntu's git main

```
git clone git://kernel.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-focal.git
```

Then proceeded to configure the kernel

```
LANG=C fakeroot debian/rules clean
LANG=C fakeroot debian/rules editconfigs
```

Go to "General Setup/Timer Subsystem/Timer Tick Handling"

Click on "Full Dynticks System"

Go to "Preemption Model"

Select "No Forced Preemption (server)"

Repeat that for the low latency kernel and at exit I get these configuration errors

```
check-config: /tmp/tmp.B1SJkC9a1n/CONFIGS/amd64-config.flavour.generic: loading config
check-config: /src/ubuntu-focal/debian.master/config/annotations loading annotations
check-config: FAIL (n != y): CONFIG_NO_HZ policy<{'amd64': 'y', 'arm64': 'y', 'armhf': 
     'y', 'i386': 'y', 'ppc64el': 'y', 's390x': 'y'}>
check-config: FAIL (n != -): CONFIG_CONTEXT_TRACKING_FORCE policy<{'amd64': '-', 
       'arm64': '-', 'armhf': '-', 'i386': '-', 'ppc64el': '-', 's390x': '-'}> 
       note<LP:1349028> mark<ENFORCED>
check-config: FAIL (n != y): CONFIG_NO_HZ_IDLE policy<{'amd64': 'y', 'arm64': 'y', 
       'armhf': 'y', 'i386': 'y', 'ppc64el': 'y', 's390x': 'y'}> note<LP:1413968>
check-config: FAIL (y != n): CONFIG_NO_HZ_FULL policy<{'amd64': 'n', 'arm64': 'n', 
       'armhf': 'n', 'ppc64el': 'n'}>
check-config: FAIL (- != y): CONFIG_TICK_CPU_ACCOUNTING policy<{'amd64': 'y', 'arm64': 'y', 
       'armhf': 'y', 'i386': 'y', 'ppc64el': 'y', }>
check-config: FAIL (y != n): CONFIG_VIRT_CPU_ACCOUNTING_GEN policy<{'amd64': 'n', 
       'arm64': 'n', 'armhf': 'n', 'ppc64el': 'n'}>
```

If I proceed to compile the binary, it will eventually fail.

I feel like I'm going on a wild goose chase here by trying to tweak parameters manually. Is there a missing step here somewhere?

I am very confused by these check-config messages, I am not sure what they mean.

Note: I made sure I could fully compile a kernel without the modifications above. It works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never had much success using the referenced method for compiling the kernel.
The configuration change you are attempting to make has some follow on configuration dependencies and they appear to be a challenge for `check-config`. If I just make the one change and then let the compile process figure out the rest, I get:

```
doug@s19:~/kernel/linux$ scripts/diffconfig .config-6.0-rc5 .config
-TICK_CPU_ACCOUNTING y
 NO_HZ_FULL n -> y
 NO_HZ_IDLE y -> n
 VIRT_CPU_ACCOUNTING_GEN n -> y
+CONTEXT_TRACKING_USER y
+CONTEXT_TRACKING_USER_FORCE n
+RCU_NOCB_CPU y
+RCU_NOCB_CPU_DEFAULT_ALL n
+VIRT_CPU_ACCOUNTING y
```

Some of those you can see in your `check-config` list of errors.
Using [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/718381/how-to-compile-and-install-custom-mainline-kernel/718662#718662) method, the kernel compiled fine for me, albeit 6.0-rc5 low latency.

Comment: There is an issue with your method that you do not create a .deb file for easy installation.

Comment: ???? My method creates .deb files (2, image and headers) for easy installation and kernel management.

Comment: there are 12 deb files created by the debian/rules binary command.

Comment: The two methods differ in the .deb file contents, with Ubuntu splitting things up into multiple .deb file and compiling multiple flavors.

Comment: Finally I got it done: https://lucisqr.substack.com/p/compiling-a-tickless-kernel-on-ubuntu

Comment: In `debian/rules.d/4-checks.mk` the `config-prepare-check-%` rule references `"$(skipconfig)" "$(do_enforce_all)"`.

So using a build line like

`LANG=C fakeroot debian/rules do_doc_package=false do_tools_perf_jvmti=false do_cloud_tools=false do_enforce_all=false do_tools_hyperv=false skipconfig=true binary-headers binary-generic binary-perarc` got around the config check errors.

Answer (score 1):

There is a useful guidance from Canonical posted as the accepted answer [here](https://support.xilinx.com/s/question/0D54U00005WclaaSAB/kernel-config-error-on-certified-ubuntu-2204-notei-tried-to-use-tag-ubuntuxilinxzynqmp5150101314-as-base-source-code?language=en_US):

> "The annotations files are managed by Canonical and are used to prevent kernel config mistakes from being made during the maintenance period. If someone is modifying the kernel configs , we assume they know what they are doing and we recommend they disable annotation checks.
>
> <...>
>
> To disable annotation checks, you can run the following command:
>
> `fakeroot debian/rules editconfigs do_enforce_all=false`

So, for the most part, it is unnecessary to actually edit the annotaitons by hand and those checks can (and should) just be skipped with `do_enforce_all=false`.

> Note: when changing configs non-interactively, such as with `scripts/config`, same parameter can be passed to `fakeroot debian/rules updateconfigs do_enforce_all=false`

An exception to this are the rules marked with `mark<ENFORCED>` which are enforced regardless. Specifically, `CONTEXT_TRACKING_FORCE` is enforced as undefined. This [was done](https://git.launchpad.net/%7Eubuntu-kernel/ubuntu/+source/linux/+git/xenial/commit/debian.master/config/annotations?id=44c85dbbdbbedd4b74be189c01ae9d4a59026138) to prevent users inadvertently enabling it, however it has to be defined when `NO_HZ_FULL` is enabled. So despite the fact that disabling it is the correct thing to do, there is no way to pass the check. The workaround is to comment out the annotation line enforcing it:

```bash
sed -e '/LP:1349028/ s/^#*/#/' -i ./debian.master/config/annotations
```

Note that same `do_enforce_all=false` setting should also be passed to skip annotation checks during the build itself:

```bash
fakeroot debian/rules do_enforce_all=false binary
```

Answer (score 0):

OK this is solved. If you came across here following that kernel guide, the issue is that the `check-config` script checks that the configuration in the kernel be exactly the golden one they published.

This means that if you change a single configuration entry , you will have to edit the file `debian.master/config/annotations`, search for the respective entry and change the setting for your platform (amd64 in my case).

Another mistake I did was to edit `debian.master/config/annotations` while trying to compile the branch `origin/hwe-5.15.0`. If you are not in master, you should edit `debian.hwe-5.15.0/config/annotations` instead.

Once you get all changed by hand, you can compile the kernel without problems.

Report:
https://lucisqr.substack.com/p/compiling-a-tickless-kernel-on-ubuntu

Comment: Very interesting article. I also read up on isolating CPUs.