# Kernel 6.3 custom compile error

Tags: kernel, compiling

I've been compiling my own kernels for and have hit an error with kernel 6.3:

$ make LSMOD=$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/modprobed.db localmodconfig
$ make deb-pkg -j4 LOCALVERSION=-custom

```
 UPD     include/config/kernel.release
  GEN     debian
error: creating source package requires git repository
make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.package:40: check-git] Error 1
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
warning: Not a git repository. Use --no-index to compare two paths outside a working tree
usage: git diff --no-index [<options>] <path> <path>

Diff output format options
    -p, --patch           generate patch
    -s, --no-patch        suppress diff output
    -u                    generate patch
    -U, --unified[=<n>]   generate diffs with <n> lines context
    -W, --function-context
                          generate diffs with <n> lines context
    --raw                 generate the diff in raw format
    --patch-with-raw      synonym for '-p --raw'
    --patch-with-stat     synonym for '-p --stat'
    --numstat             machine friendly --stat
    --shortstat           output only the last line of --stat
    -X, --dirstat[=<param1,param2>...]
                          output the distribution of relative amount of changes for each sub-directory
    --cumulative          synonym for --dirstat=cumulative
    --dirstat-by-file[=<param1,param2>...]
                          synonym for --dirstat=files,param1,param2...
    --check               warn if changes introduce conflict markers or whitespace errors
    --summary             condensed summary such as creations, renames and mode changes
    --name-only           show only names of changed files
    --name-status         show only names and status of changed files
    --stat[=<width>[,<name-width>[,<count>]]]
                          generate diffstat
    --stat-width <width>  generate diffstat with a given width
    --stat-name-width <width>
                          generate diffstat with a given name width
    --stat-graph-width <width>
                          generate diffstat with a given graph width
    --stat-count <count>  generate diffstat with limited lines
    --compact-summary     generate compact summary in diffstat
    --binary              output a binary diff that can be applied
    --full-index          show full pre- and post-image object names on the "index" lines
    --color[=<when>]      show colored diff
    --ws-error-highlight <kind>
                          highlight whitespace errors in the 'context', 'old' or 'new' lines in the diff
    -z                    do not munge pathnames and use NULs as output field terminators in --raw or --numstat
    --abbrev[=<n>]        use <n> digits to display object names
    --src-prefix <prefix>
                          show the given source prefix instead of "a/"
    --dst-prefix <prefix>
                          show the given destination prefix instead of "b/"
    --line-prefix <prefix>
                          prepend an additional prefix to every line of output
    --no-prefix           do not show any source or destination prefix
    --inter-hunk-context <n>
                          show context between diff hunks up to the specified number of lines
    --output-indicator-new <char>
                          specify the character to indicate a new line instead of '+'
    --output-indicator-old <char>
                          specify the character to indicate an old line instead of '-'
    --output-indicator-context <char>
                          specify the character to indicate a context instead of ' '

Diff rename options
    -B, --break-rewrites[=<n>[/<m>]]
                          break complete rewrite changes into pairs of delete and create
    -M, --find-renames[=<n>]
                          detect renames
    -D, --irreversible-delete
                          omit the preimage for deletes
    -C, --find-copies[=<n>]
                          detect copies
    --find-copies-harder  use unmodified files as source to find copies
    --no-renames          disable rename detection
    --rename-empty        use empty blobs as rename source
    --follow              continue listing the history of a file beyond renames
    -l <n>                prevent rename/copy detection if the number of rename/copy targets exceeds given limit

Diff algorithm options
    --minimal             produce the smallest possible diff
    -w, --ignore-all-space
                          ignore whitespace when comparing lines
    -b, --ignore-space-change
                          ignore changes in amount of whitespace
    --ignore-space-at-eol
                          ignore changes in whitespace at EOL
    --ignore-cr-at-eol    ignore carrier-return at the end of line
    --ignore-blank-lines  ignore changes whose lines are all blank
    -I, --ignore-matching-lines <regex>
                          ignore changes whose all lines match <regex>
    --indent-heuristic    heuristic to shift diff hunk boundaries for easy reading
    --patience            generate diff using the "patience diff" algorithm
    --histogram           generate diff using the "histogram diff" algorithm
    --diff-algorithm <algorithm>
                          choose a diff algorithm
    --anchored <text>     generate diff using the "anchored diff" algorithm
    --word-diff[=<mode>]  show word diff, using <mode> to delimit changed words
    --word-diff-regex <regex>
                          use <regex> to decide what a word is
    --color-words[=<regex>]
                          equivalent to --word-diff=color --word-diff-regex=<regex>
    --color-moved[=<mode>]
                          moved lines of code are colored differently
    --color-moved-ws <mode>
                          how white spaces are ignored in --color-moved

Other diff options
    --relative[=<prefix>]
                          when run from subdir, exclude changes outside and show relative paths
    -a, --text            treat all files as text
    -R                    swap two inputs, reverse the diff
    --exit-code           exit with 1 if there were differences, 0 otherwise
    --quiet               disable all output of the program
    --ext-diff            allow an external diff helper to be executed
    --textconv            run external text conversion filters when comparing binary files
    --ignore-submodules[=<when>]
                          ignore changes to submodules in the diff generation
    --submodule[=<format>]
                          specify how differences in submodules are shown
    --ita-invisible-in-index
                          hide 'git add -N' entries from the index
    --ita-visible-in-index
                          treat 'git add -N' entries as real in the index
    -S <string>           look for differences that change the number of occurrences of the specified string
    -G <regex>            look for differences that change the number of occurrences of the specified regex
    --pickaxe-all         show all changes in the changeset with -S or -G
    --pickaxe-regex       treat <string> in -S as extended POSIX regular expression
    -O <file>             control the order in which files appear in the output
    --rotate-to <path>    show the change in the specified path first
    --skip-to <path>      skip the output to the specified path
    --find-object <object-id>
                          look for differences that change the number of occurrences of the specified object
    --diff-filter [(A|C|D|M|R|T|U|X|B)...[*]]
                          select files by diff type
    --output <file>       output to a specific file

make: *** [Makefile:1656: deb-pkg] Error 2
```

Does anyone have any advice on how to fix this?
Thanks.

Ubuntu 23.04

Comment: Not the kernel 23.04 comes with why are you trying to do this?

Comment: Try `make bindeb-pkg -j4 LOCALVERSION=-custom`. But please tell us more about what you doing and why. see also [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/718381/how-to-compile-and-install-custom-mainline-kernel/718662#718662).

Comment: Hey again. Why am I doing this? No crucial reason. Everything works fine on my laptop. I've been building my own custom kernels specific to my hardware for a few years and I've never received this kind of an error before.  These are the commands I've always used to make the deb pkgs for install. Just surprised by a 'git' error of all things.

Comment: Okay. Tried the 'bindeb-pkg' command above and it worked. Not sure why it changed but oh well. Many thanks :)

Comment: Glad you got it to work. It was years ago I had to change to `bindeb-pkg`. However, while looking into your question, I tried `deb-pkg` and it worked!!!

Comment: Thanks. It is a little weird about deb-pkg, isn’t it? I’ve used that command for years - even yesterday when I recompiled 6.2.12 just to see and it worked as always. Weird.

Answer (score 3):

March 16, 2023  [linux kernel git commit](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=05e96e96a315fa49faca4da2aedd1761a218b616) 05e96e96a315fa49faca4da2aedd1761a218b616

> kbuild: use git-archive for source package creation Commit 5c3d1d0
> ("kbuild: add a tool to list files ignored by git") added a new tool,
> scripts/list-gitignored. My intention was to create source packages
> without cleaning the source tree, without relying on git.
>
> Linus strongly objected to it, and suggested using 'git archive'
> instead. [1] [2] [3]
>
> This commit goes in that direction - Remove scripts/list-gitignored.c
> and rewrites Makefiles and scripts to use 'git archive' for building
> Debian and RPM source packages. It also makes 'make perf-tar*-src-pkg'
> use 'git archive' again.
>
> Going forward, building source packages is only possible in a
> git-managed tree. Building binary packages does not require git.

So according to the above commit, just use "make bindeb-pkg" or if you want to build src pkg using "make deb-pkg" like before (pre 6.3), then you have to git pull the kernel source tree.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks so much for your explanation. Kudos.

Answer (score 1):

The same for me, for unknown reasons, the command 'make deb-pkg' won't work (it worked fo years without problems), the suggested command 'make bindeb-pkg' worked. This only for the 6.3 kernel release.

Comment: How does this differ from the answer by @gniuk?