# How to rebuild the kernel in 20.04 without debian/rules clean

Tags: drivers, kernel, compiling, debian, fakeroot

After downloading the source and i can

```
LANG=C fakeroot debian/rules binary-headers binary-generic binary-perarch
```

to build the kernel,
but if i change a file in the kernel drivers and run it again,
the deb image is not updated,
and `debian/rules clean`,then rebuild takes too long.

How do i not clean it and perform the rebuild for my kernel driver?

Comment: I only know how to do incremental (non-clean) kernel compiles using the mainline method detailed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/718381/how-to-compile-and-install-custom-mainline-kernel/718662#718662)