# How to install kernel 6.5 from Mainline PPA into Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

Tags: nvidia, kernel, 22.04, ppa

I need the newest nct6775 and asus-ec-sensors modules from the 6.5 kernel branches for my Asus X670E Hero motherboard and Ryzen 7950X cpu to get sensors for my cpu and motherboard.

Every time I attempt to install from the Mainline PPA, the kernel installation errors out with an apport dkms error -10 for the nvidia-driver-535 drivers. Consulting the error log in /lib/modules/6.5-rc5-generic/nvidia/build.log tells me the nvidia modules can't be compiled because of a compiler mismatch.  The kernels are built with gcc13 and the system only has gcc11.

This leaves me with no video drivers.  The highest kernel that will install is the default HWE kernel 6.2.0-26 in the new Ubuntu ISO.

This only provides me only k10temp module for sensors. Neither nct6775 nor asus-ec-sensors modules in kernel 6.2.0-26 can find my motherboard and are uninstallable.

How does one install the latest kernels when you have a compiler mismatch?

Comment: I would suggest you recompile the entire kernel locally on your computer. I use [this method](https://askubuntu.com/questions/718381/how-to-compile-and-install-custom-mainline-kernel/718662#718662), using gcc 10.