# Tutorial request on how to bisect the kernel

Tags: kernel, git

Many times after the kernel upgrade something has stopped working or started crashing. The very last one that provoked me to submit this question is vscode.

I need to run it with --disable-gpu now. I would like to find the root cause of this (and any other similar issue) by bisecting the kernel - starting at particular version that worked and then apply one patch a time (or set of patches) to see which caused this problem.

I would appreciate some good Ubuntu-specific howto on this topic - with possible script automating the task. Thanks.

Comment: That's called _bisecting_, not _dissecting_.

Comment: This is a very primitive, obsolete, high effort, method to addres your problems. Address and solve individual, smaller problems. Been There, Done That.

Comment: Bisecting the kernel is reasonably straight forward, but is tedious and takes time. While you ask for "Ubuntu-specific how to" it is best too use the upstream mainline git code and to bisect it. For git bisect how to see [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect). For how to get and compile mainline see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/718381/how-to-compile-and-install-custom-mainline-kernel/718662#718662)